# How can I control 'TraditionalForm' substitutions and formatting in special cases?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, traditional-form

I [have](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76728/37)

```
eqns = TraditionalForm[HoldForm[Subscript[W, #][#] = ρ^s[#] Subscript[ω, #] ρ^-s[#]],] & /@ Range[4]
```

which (with `eqns//TableForm`) give me

$$
W_1(1)=\rho ^{s(1)} \omega _1 \rho ^{-s(1)}\\
W_2(2)=\rho ^{s(2)} \omega _2 \rho ^{-s(2)}\\
W_3(3)=\rho ^{s(3)} \omega _3 \rho ^{-s(3)}\\
W_4(4)=\rho ^{s(4)} \omega _4 \rho ^{-s(4)}
$$

as I expect. But I need to substitute evaluations of `s` for various argument values. When I do this, for many values of `s` I get what I expect; but for others, I'm failing the get substitutions I need, or get odd reformatting that I don't expect. For example if `s[#]& /@ {1,2,3,4}` happens to be `{0,23,10,-1}`, I get

$$
W_1(1)=\rho ^0 \omega _1 \rho ^0\\
W_2(2)=\rho ^{23} \omega _2 \rho ^{-23}\\
W_3(3)=\rho ^{10} \omega _3 \rho ^{-10}\\
W_4=\frac{\rho ^{-(-1)} \omega _4}{\rho }
$$

when what I need is

$$
W_1(1)=\omega _1\\
W_2(2)=\rho ^{23} \omega _2 \rho ^{-23}\\
W_3(3)=\rho ^{10} \omega _3 \rho ^{-10}\\
W_2(2)=\rho ^{-1} \omega _2 \rho ^{1}\\
$$

How can I get *Mathematica* the make the correct substitutions?

Comment: Much worse, *Mathematica* [does not correctly copy](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76860/37) any of these expressions as *LaTeX*.

Answer (score 1):

```
formatter[fab_, c_] := Block[{p1, p2, lhs, rhs, fn},
  rhs = If[fab == 0, Subscript[\[Omega], c], 
  If[fab < 0, fn = Abs[fab]; 
  HoldForm[\[Rho]^-f Subscript[\[Omega], c] \[Rho]^f] /. f -> fn, 
  HoldForm[\[Rho]^fab Subscript[\[Omega], c] \[Rho]^-fab]]];
  lhs = Subscript[W, fab][c];
  Replace[Evaluate[{lhs, rhs}], 
  List[a__, b__] :> HoldForm[Set[a , b]], Heads -> True]]
```

And then

```
 formatter[0,2]
```

or

```
formatter[-1,2]
```

etc.

Of course you can use `formatter[-1,2]//TeXForm` or `//TraditionalForm` if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want *Mathematica* to perform some simplifications of your expression, I don't think this is purely formatting question.

Inferring from your desired simplifications of $\rho^i\omega\rho^{-i}$ for different $i$, it is supposed to be some form of multiplication, but different than built-in `Times` function.

I would start with defining desired properties of your multiplication. To get results from examples in question this should be enough:

```
ClearAll[myTimes]
myTimes[l___, 1, r___] := myTimes[l, r]
(* To make it more similar to multiplication, you could add something like: *)
(*myTimes[___,0,___]=0;
myTimes[l___,x_,x_,r___]:=myTimes[l,x^2,r]
myTimes[x_]:=x
myTimes[]=1;
SetAttributes[myTimes,{Flat,OneIdentity}]*)
(* but this is not needed for examples from question. *)
```

Now let's assign desired formatting to `myTimes` function:

```
ClearAll[toPowerBoxes];
SetAttributes[toPowerBoxes, HoldAllComplete]
toPowerBoxes[{expr___}, form_] :=
    List @@ Replace[
        HoldComplete[expr],
        {
            Power[x_, y_] :> SuperscriptBox[MakeBoxes[x, form], MakeBoxes[y, form]], 
            x_ :> MakeBoxes[x, form]
        },
        {1}
    ]
MakeBoxes[HoldPattern@myTimes[expr__], StandardForm] ^:=
    RowBox[{"myTimes", "[", RowBox[Riffle[toPowerBoxes[{expr}, StandardForm], ","]], "]"}]
MakeBoxes[HoldPattern@myTimes[expr__], TraditionalForm] ^:=
    With[{boxes = RowBox[toPowerBoxes[{expr}, TraditionalForm]]},
        InterpretationBox[boxes, myTimes[expr]]
    ]
```

Examples from question, with unevaluated `s`:

```
Subscript[W, #][#] == myTimes[ρ^s[#] , Subscript[ω, #], ρ^-s[#]] & /@ Range[4]
% // TableForm // TraditionalForm
```

> $\{W_1[1] == \text{myTimes}[\rho^{s[1]}, \omega_1, \rho^{-s[1]}], ...\}$

```
(*Out[]//TraditionalForm=*)
```

> $W_1(1)=\rho ^{s(1)}\omega _1\rho ^{-s(1)} \\
> ...$

and when `s` evaluates to something:

```
Block[{s},
    s[1] = 0; s[2] = 23; s[3] = 10; s[4] = -1;
    Subscript[W, #][#] == myTimes[ρ^s[#] , Subscript[ω, #], ρ^-s[#]] & /@ Range[4]
]
% // TableForm // TraditionalForm
% // TableForm // TeXForm
```

> $\{
> W_1[1] == \text{myTimes}[\omega_1],
> W_2[2] == \text{myTimes}[\rho^{23}, \omega_2, \rho^{-23}],
> W_3[3] == \text{myTimes}[\rho^{10}, \omega_3, \rho^{-10}],
> W_4[4] == \text{myTimes}[\rho^{-1}, \omega_4, \rho]
> \}$

```
(*Out[]//TraditionalForm=*)
```

> $W_1(1)=\omega _1 \\
>  W_2(2)=\rho ^{23}\omega _2\rho ^{-23} \\
>  W_3(3)=\rho ^{10}\omega _3\rho ^{-10} \\
>  W_4(4)=\rho ^{-1}\omega _4\rho$

```
(*Out[]//TeXForm=
\begin{array}{c}
 W_1(1)=\omega _1 \\
 W_2(2)=\rho ^{23}\omega _2\rho ^{-23} \\
 W_3(3)=\rho ^{10}\omega _3\rho ^{-10} \\
 W_4(4)=\rho ^{-1}\omega _4\rho  \\
\end{array}*)
```

You can also select `StandardForm` expression containing `myTimes` and use *Copy As > LaTeX*. Result is the same as output of `TeXForm`.