# How do I prevent Mathematica from reformatting the expressions that I copy as LaTeX?

Tags: bugs, formatting, latex

When I choose [something](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76728/37) that looks like

$$
W_1(1)=\rho ^{5} \omega _1 \rho ^{-5}\\
W_2(2)=\rho ^{23} \omega _2 \rho ^{-23}\\
W_3(3)=\rho ^{10} \omega _3 \rho ^{-10}\\
W_4(4)=\rho ^{9} \omega _4 \rho ^{-9}
$$

in *Mathematica* and select **Copy As > LaTeX** I get something *entirely different*:

$$
W_1(1)=\frac{\rho ^5 \omega _1}{\rho ^5}\\
W_2(2)=\frac{\rho ^{23} \omega _2}{\rho ^{23}}\\
W_3(3)=\frac{\rho ^{10} \omega _3}{\rho ^{10}}\\
W_4(4)=\frac{\rho ^9 \omega _4}{\rho ^9}
$$

How do I prevent *Mathematica* from reformatting the expressions that I copy as *LaTeX*?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what your scenario is, but if you're just interested in typesetting, then [this recent answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76650/245) may be applicable.

Comment: @Jens: I was hoping to find a way to prevent MMA from changing the formatting of my expressions when I copied them. (A pretty general "scenario".)

Comment: Yes, but how are you creating the "expressions" - the question should probably state that they are generated as output from *Mathematica* code (just guessing). The other scenario would be that you are just typing them in by hand. The optimal solutions would be quite different depending on the starting point...

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Is my answer of any help?

Comment: @Jens: A, sorry, I forgot to [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76728/37).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, the *Mathematica*'s *Copy As > LaTeX* command is *not* (as you'd expect) a command that copies the selected expressions as *LaTeX*. Instead, it performs additional reformatting that can only be avoided by changing behavior of the relevant built-in function with:

```
System`FEDump`CopyAsTeXMakeBoxes = #&
```

---

### Details

#### Why copied boxes are reformatted

**Copy As > LaTeX** command, under the hood, calls `` FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX `` function.

If we [spelunk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15948/14303) it:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/szhorvat/Spelunking/master/Spelunking.m"]
Spelunk@FrontEnd`CopyAsTeX
```

we'll see it performs several steps. Relevant, for answer to this question, is call to `` System`FEDump`TransformBoxesToTraditionalFormBoxes `` function.
We can "discover" it using pop-up that appears after clicking on this function's name.

We'll see that, basically, it calls `MakeExpression[..., "StandardForm"]` on given boxes, than passes resulting expression to
`` System`FEDump`CopyAsTeXMakeBoxes `` function, together with boxes.
`CopyAsTeXMakeBoxes` function calls `MakeBoxes[..., "TraditionalForm"]` on given expression.

This is the place where reformatting occurs.

If we take expression from question and pass it, converted to boxes, to `TransformBoxesToTraditionalFormBoxes` we'll get:

```
HoldForm[Equal[Subscript[W,1][1],Times[Power[ρ,5],Subscript[ω,1],Power[ρ,Times[-1,5]]]]] // MakeBoxes
System`FEDump`TransformBoxesToTraditionalFormBoxes[%]
(* TagBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{SubscriptBox[W,1],(,1,)}],==,FractionBox[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[ρ,5], ,SubscriptBox[ω,1]}],SuperscriptBox[ρ,5]]}],HoldForm] *)
% // DisplayForm
```

> $W_1(1)=\frac{\rho ^5 \omega _1}{\rho ^5}$

We see that `HoldForm` `TagBox` is still there.
`TransformBoxesToTraditionalFormBoxes` and `CopyAsTeXMakeBoxes` are written in safe way, there's no evaluation leak. Expression created from boxes is wrapped with `HoldComplete` and function applied to it has properly set `HoldAllComplete` attribute. Reformatting is done purely by `MakeBoxes` function.

`TransformBoxesToTraditionalFormBoxes` was added in *Mathematica* version 9.
Verison 8 copies expressions without reformatting.

#### How to change **Copy As > LaTeX** behavior

`` System`FEDump`CopyAsTeXMakeBoxes `` takes two arguments first are (almost) original boxes, second is expression obtained from those boxes. Original boxes are returned when reconverting expression to boxes encounters any problems.

If we don't mind changing behavior of built-in function, we can force `CopyAsTeXMakeBoxes` to always return unchanged boxes by setting:

```
System`FEDump`CopyAsTeXMakeBoxes = #&
```

Solution tested in *Mathematica* versions 9 and 10. Previous versions don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the command name, "Copy As LaTeX", *Mathematica*'s frontend does not just copy the material in the frontend, but evaluates it first, which indicates a round-trip to the kernel with any `HoldForm` etc. stripped: Your expressions *will be evaluated* when creating the $\TeX$ representation.

Your only recourse is to create a workaround that explicitly uses `TeXForm` to create $\TeX$ representation.

For example, you can use `TeXForm` and the answers to your other [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76728/how-i-create-a-traditionalform-expression-in-which-only-parts-are-evaluated):

Just apply `TeXForm` and get, e.g.:

```
W_5(1)=\rho^5\omega(1)\rho^{-5}
```

which happily formats in $\TeX$ as

$$W_5(1)=\rho ^5 \omega (1) \rho ^{-5}$$

**Putting it all together:** Use

```
TeXForm@HoldForm[Subscript[W,f[a,b]][c]=\[Rho]^f[a,b]\[Omega][c]\[Rho]^-f[a,b]]//.{f[a,b]->5,c->1}
```

Comment: That process TeX in MMA. I need the expression as is in the Notebook, but when I *copy* I don't want it to *change*.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Then you might be at a loss. But my "workaround" gives you the opportunity to just copy the output it produces and have what you need, no?

Comment: Yes. I'll hold for a bit before accepting and see if another solution turns up. But this may be as close as I get. (Typical *Mathematica*; every day I use it I find myself wondering why!)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Looks like there is no other solution coming up. ;)

Comment: Can you confirm that it is impossible to *prevent* this (buggy) behavior of Mathematica? I'd like the answer to address that: e.g, "Mathematica's 'Copy As > LaTeX' command is *not* (as you'd expect) a WYSIWYG command but is really a 'simplify and then copy the result' command. In Mathematica there's no way to copy what you see; but you can manually generate LaTeX when you need wit with:"

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I updated the answer to reflect my findings on this issue more clearly.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Did my answer work out for you? If so, I would be glad if you accepted it.

Comment: Would everybody please refrain from times and again changing my answer?

Comment: We have (in effect) two votes for revision 4. I think we should stick with that (that's what I'll accept).

Comment: @Jinxed "... with any `HoldForm` etc. stripped: Your expressions *will be evaluated* ..." are you sure about this? I can select `1+2` in notebook choose "Copy As LaTeX" and get `1+2` not `3`, it's the same e.g. for output of `HoldForm[1+2]`. I don't believe reformatting from question is caused by evaluation of copied expression. I think it's done at level of `MakeBoxes` or equivalent function, as I tried to describe it in [answer to raxacoricofallapatorius`s previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76923/14303).

Comment: What precisely happens depends on what precisely you select in notebook. And whether you select as much as *Mathematica* needs to know that you're copying `TraditionalForm` boxes, otherwise they will be interpreted as `StandardForm` boxes and *Mathematica* will reconvert them to `TraditionalForm` boxes.

Comment: @jkuczm: For the OP's question, the behavior is just as described. There may be other situations, but the case at hand is as described in the answer.