# Can one prevent operators like `Factor` or `Apart` from changing full form of some algebraic expressions?

Tags: output-formatting, algebraic-manipulation

In this question I will talk about a toy example, it should be clear what do I actually mean in general. Also, not only [`Factor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html) but also [`Apart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apart.html) and several other important operators have this behavior.

Say, `Factor[1/(1 - t)]` produces `-(1/(-1 + t))` which is not just formatting but full form change: `FullForm[1/(1 - t)]` is

```
Power[Plus[1,Times[-1,t]],-1]
```

while `FullForm[Factor[1/(1 - t)]]` gives

```
Times[-1,Power[Plus[-1,t],-1]]
```

which I find sort of inconvenient sometimes. Not that I care about internals of representing objects, most probably it is optimized in some way, but when I need to work with such expressions, introduction of redundant extra minus signs, etc. is which I find inconvenient.

What would be the correct way to deal with this? One related question I found is [How to put terms in lexicographic order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9483/35000) where one of possibilities named was to issue

```
$PrePrint = PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &;
```

but some adverse effects of it were also mentioned. And in fact, `TraditionalOrder` is not what I would need anyway, it gives something still different, namely (in this particular case) `-(1/(t-1))`.

Also, after having posted the question, I discovered in the **Related** column to the right another one, [How do I prevent Mathematica from reformatting the expressions that I copy as LaTeX?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76860/35000), but also in this case I cannot really figure out whether I can use answers there for my purposes.

As suggested by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey) here is a more illustrative example. Issuing

[image]

gives

[image]

while what I would like to see is

[image]

Comment: Work-arounds tend to be problem-specific, in my experience.  In this case, `Simplify` restores `-(1/(-1 + t))` to the desired form.  Perhaps, you could provide a typical expression with which you are having such problems.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I encounter such expressions systematically, just to give an example - `Apart[((1-3 t^2-t w+t^2 w+5 t^3 w-t^2 w^2-2 t^3 w^2)z w)/((1-3 t^2) (1-w) (1-2 t w)(1-z w)),w]` gives `-((t (1+2 t))/(2 (-1+3 t^2)))+(-z+t z)/((-1+2 t) (-1+w) (-1+z))-(t (-z+2 t^2 z))/(2 (-1+2 t) (-1+3 t^2) (-1+2 t w) (2 t-z))-(-t^2-2 t^3-t z+t^2 z+5 t^3 z+z^2-3 t^2 z^2)/((-1+3 t^2) (2 t-z) (-1+z) (-1+w z))`. `Simplify` just puts it all together in this case which is not what I want, while `Map[Simplify,%]` does not change anything.

Comment: `PolynomialForm` appears to work well in this case.  As I remarked above, such work-arounds tend to be problem-specific.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Could you please post this as an answer, with details? How exactly can I use `PolynomialForm`?

Comment: As requested, I have provided as an answer the use of `PolynomialForm` applied to the expression in your comment above.  However, you should not expect it to give you the desired form in all cases.  Also, I recommend against using $PrePrint for the reasons given in [How to put terms in lexicographic order](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9490/1063).

Answer (score 2):

The following functions seem to produce the desired result. (**Edited** to simplify functions.)

```
f[x_] := Quiet@Module[{ct = 1, den, vv = Denominator[x]}, 
    v = If[Head[vv] === Times, List @@ vv, {vv}]; 
    den = Times @@ (If[IntegerQ[#[[1]]] && #[[1]] < 0, ct = -ct; -#, #] & /@ v);
    Simplify[ct Numerator[x]]/den]
g[x_] := Module[{v}, v = If[Head[x] === Plus, List @@ x, {x}]; Plus @@ Map[f, List @@ v]]
```

Applied to the expressions in the question,

```
ex = 1/(1 - t);
ans = Factor[ex];
g[ans]
(* 1/(1 - t) *)

ex = (1 + t - t^2 - t z - 2 t^2 z)/(1 - 2 t z);
ans = Apart[ex, z];
g[ans]
(* 1/2 (1 + 2 t) + (1 - 2 t^2)/(2 (1 - 2 t z)) *)
```

as requested.  A more challenging expression is that given by the OP in a comment above.

```
ex = ((1 - 3 t^2 - t w + t^2 w + 5 t^3 w - t^2 w^2 - 
    2 t^3 w^2) z w)/((1 - 3 t^2) (1 - w) (1 - 2 t w) (1 - z w));
ans = Apart[ex, z];
g[ans]
(* (t (1 + 2 t))/(2 (1 - 3 t^2)) + (t (-1 + 2 t^2) z)/(2 (1 - 2 t) (1 - 3 t^2) 
   (1 - 2 t w) (2 t - z)) + (z - t z)/((1 - 2 t) (1 - w) (1 - z)) + 
   (-t z + z^2 + t^3 (-2 + 5 z) + t^2 (-1 + z - 3 z^2))/((1 - 3 t^2) (1 - z) 
   (2 t - z) (1 - w z)) *)
```

This too appears to meet the OP's goal.  The accuracy of any of the three examples can be verified by

```
Simplify[% - %%]
(* 0 *)
```

The overall strategy of this approach is to decompose `ans` into a `List` of ratios of polynomials, decompose the factors in the denominator of each `List` element into other `List`, recast those denominator elements into the form requested by the OP, and then reassemble the ratios and `ans` itself.  `f` handles the inner `List`, and `g` the outer.  Note that

```
v = If[Head[x] === Plus, List @@ x, {x}];
```

has been inserted into `g`, and a similar expression into `f`, in an **edit** to accommodate the special cases of an `ans` that contains only a single term (as in the first example) or a `Denominator` that contains only a single factor (as in the third example with `ex` replaced by `2 ex`).

Comment: Thank you for help. Unfortunately this does not always work - in some cases it does not change the expression (for example `g[(-2+3t)/(1-t)]` returns the same `(-2+3t)/(1-t)`) while in some other cases it performs simplifications which might or might not be desirable (for example `g[-((-1+t) (1+t))/t^2]` gives `(1-t^2)/t^2`). Still, inspired by your approach I came up with something which I will post as an answer. I am not sure if this always works, although I tested it a bit. In any case, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey)'s answer I came up with what hopefully gives a solution. I am not accepting it yet though, in case I've overlooked something.

```
myForm[x_] :=
 Which[
  NumberQ[x] || Head[x] === Symbol, x,
  Head[x] === Plus && Select[x, NumberQ] < 0, With[{t = Map[myForm, -x]}, -HoldForm[t]],
  True, ReleaseHold[Map[myForm, x]]
 ]
```

Comment: Quite elegant recursive solution (+1).  Glad I could help.  By the way, I am uncertain whether someone can upvote or accept his own answer.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I know I cannot upvote but can accept. I'm still waiting for somebody probably give still cleaner solution. For mine so far I discovered one undesirable thing: `myForm[-1+a]` gives `-(1-a)` but `myForm[-(1-a)]` gives `-1+a` back. Potentially this might produce infinite loops somehow...