# NMinimize works only if expression is pasted directly

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Niminize works fine if I copy the minimized function directly by hands, but doesn't work if I try to do something like this:

```
exp=minimizedExpression;
f[variables_]:=NMinimize[{exp,constraints},{...}]
```

then it fails.

Particular example:

```
exp = (-(1/f) - ((1 + a)^(1 + m)
  m x (a + x)^(-1 - m))/λ + (-a + (1 + a)^(
  1 + m) (a + x)^-m)/λ)^2 + (-((3 w)/f) - (
3 (1 + a)^(1 + m) m X (a + X)^(-1 - m))/Λ + (
3 (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + X)^-m))/Λ)^2 + (-((
 9 (1 + a)^(1 + m) m z (a + z)^(-1 - m))/Λ) + (
9 (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + z)^-m))/Λ - (
9 τ)/
f)^2 + (-((2 (1 + a)^(1 + m) m y (a + y)^(-1 - m))/λ) + (
2 (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + y)^-m))/λ - (2 τ)/
f)^2 + (-((
 6 (1 + a)^(1 + m) m Y (a + Y)^(-1 - m))/Λ) + (
6 (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + Y)^-m))/Λ - (
6 w τ)/
f)^2 + (-((3 (1 + a)^(1 + m) m Z (a + Z)^(-1 - m))/λ) + (
3 (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + Z)^-m))/λ - (3 w τ)/
f)^2 + (-1.` + (x (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + x)^-m))/λ + (
2 y (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + y)^-m))/λ + (
9 z (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + z)^-m))/Λ - (
x + 2 y τ + 9 z τ)/
f)^2 + (-((
 z (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + z)^-m))/(Λ (1.` + (
    x + 2 y τ + 9 z τ)/f))) + (
Z (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + Z)^-m))/(λ (1.` + (
   3 X + 6 Y τ + 3 Z τ)/f)))^2 + ((
3 Z (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + Z)^-m))/λ + (
3 X (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + X)^-m))/Λ + (
6 Y (-a + (1 + a)^(1 + m) (a + Y)^-m))/Λ - 
w (1.` + (3 X + 6 Y τ + 3 Z τ)/f))^2

Clear[f$minimize2]
f$minimize2[a_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, 
  s_?NumericQ, τNotRationalized_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ] :=
 TimeConstrained[
  f$minimize2[a, m, L, s, τNotRationalized, f] = Block[
    {list, b, b$1, X, Y, Z, x, y, 
     z, τ = Rationalize[τNotRationalized]},
    b$1 = 
     NMinimize[{exp, 
       X >= 10^-12 && Y >= 10^-12 && Z >= 10^-12 && x >= 10^-12 && 
        y >= 10^-12 && 
        z >= 10^-12 && λ >= 10^-12 && Λ >= 
         10^-12 && w >= 10^-12},
      {X, Y, Z, x, y, z, λ, Λ, w}];
    b = b$1
    ]
  , 1]

f$minimize2[1., 0.25, 1., 0.5, 1., 0.3]
```

Comment: Basically,even the first version of this question showed enough code to [exactly reproduce](http://hastebin.com/laruxoqira.avrasm) the problem. This might be a question that has already been answered in different flavors on SE, but I think it is a valid question. Unfortunately, the moment I had written my answer, it was closed. Could someone at least mark this as exact duplicate and show the OP a solution? Or reopen it and I post a solution.

Comment: @halirutan It is now open.

Answer (score 3):

You basic problem can be broken down to this simple example

```
myExpr = m^2;
f[m_] := m*myExpr

f[3]
(* 3*m^2 *)
```

You can use `Trace` to see the steps of evaluation, but to cut it short here are the two steps that happen when you call `f[3]`:

1. Every occurrence of `m` in the right side of the definition of `f` is replaced by 3. This is unfortunately only one occurrence, because when you look at `??f` you see that `myExpr` is still unevaluated.
2. The body of the definition is evaluated. This is the point, where `myExpr` is replaced with its actual value. Now, we have another `m` there, but too late to insert the 3.

Now let's review the error message you get with your particular `NMinimize` example:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

It says

> *The function value...* [now a formula where all are parameters like `a` and `m` are still present appear] *...is not a number*.

Well, like in the small example above, your parameters were not replaced by the values that you have supplied in your call

```
f$minimize2[1., 0.25, 1., 0.5, 1., 0.3]
```

The solution is to insert the body of your `exp` before the assignment happens and this is the point where I cannot offer a that can directly be understood. You will have to learn about how *Mathematica* evaluates expressions and which rules it follows.

First solution: Make a pure function where the expression you try to insert is the parameter and directly call this function with your expression:

```
ClearAll[f]
myExpr = m^2;
(f[m_] := m*#) &[myExpr]
```

This works because `myExpr` is evaluated *before* it is used as argument that is inserted in the body. Therefore, at the place of the `#`, you full body of `myExpr` is inserted and not the variable name `myExpr`.

Another way is to prevent your function definition from evaluation using `Hold` and replace your expression before you give it free for evaluation (using `ReleaseHold`). This one is hard to understand, so please read this [answer of Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/187) carefully.

```
ClearAll[f]
myExpr = m^2;
Hold[f[m_] := m*placeToInsert] /. 
 placeToInsert :> With[{e = myExpr}, e /; True]
ReleaseHold[%]
```

Using the first solution on your code gives the answer you want:

```
ClearAll[f$minimize2]
(f$minimize2[a_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, L_?NumericQ, 
     s_?NumericQ, τNotRationalized_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ] := 
    f$minimize2[a, m, L, s, τNotRationalized, f] = 
     Block[{list, b, b$1, X, Y, Z, x, y, 
       z, τ = Rationalize[τNotRationalized]}, 
      b$1 = NMinimize[{#, 
         X >= 10^-12 && Y >= 10^-12 && Z >= 10^-12 && x >= 10^-12 && 
          y >= 10^-12 && 
          z >= 10^-12 && λ >= 10^-12 && Λ >= 
           10^-12 && w >= 10^-12}, {X, Y, Z, x, y, 
         z, λ, Λ, w}];
      b = b$1]) &[exp]


f$minimize2[1., 0.25, 1., 0.5, 1., 0.3]
(* {4.38851*10^-15, {X -> 0.251408, Y -> 0.251408, 
  Z -> 0.251408, x -> 0.251408, y -> 0.251408, 
  z -> 0.251408, λ -> 0.340737, Λ -> 0.340737, 
  w -> 1.}} *)
```