# Condition and RuleDelayed

Tags: replacement

On this site I found, for example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/20253), some very interesting questions and answers on the use of delayed rules with conditions. I would very much like to understand these answers, but so far I failed on a very basic level.

The documentation states that `Condition` is an expression with two arguments: a pattern and a test. Such an expression is itself a pattern, which is matched only by expressions that match the first argument and moreover for which the evaluation of test gives `True`.

Since the lefthand side of a rule is a pattern, the following works:

```
lhs /. (lhs/;True) :> rhs
(* rhs *)
```

My problem in understanding has to do with `Condition` in the right hand side of a rule. The documentation states that `lhs :> rhs /; test` represents a rule which applies only if the evaluation of `test` yields `True`. Such a rule is in fact a normal `RuleDelayed`, with the `Condition` expression as the second argument.

A `Condition` expression evaluates to itself, even when the second argument is `True`:

```
Condition[rhs,True]
(* rhs/;True *)
```

When I use a `RuleDelayed`, my understanding is that the unevaluated right hand side is substituted for any subexpression that matches the pattern of the left hand side, and then a further evaluation of the expression takes place. Therefore, I expected the result of the following two commands to be respectively `Condition[rhs, False]` and `Condition[rhs, True]`.

```
lhs /. lhs:>(rhs /; False) (* lhs *)
lhs /. lhs:>(rhs /; True) (* rhs *)
```

In the first example the rule is not used at all, in agreement with the documentation for `Condition`, but not in accordance with my understanding of `RuleDelayed`. In the second example, the rule is used, but moreover at some point the right hand side is evaluated to its first argument.

So my impression is that when we have a `RuleDelayed` with a `Condition` in the right hand side, the evaluation rules seem to be different from those without the `Condition`. That is something I cannot believe. So can someone point me to what I do not properly understand?

Comment: You may find [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866016/question-on-condition) relevant.

Comment: [1/2] Since, as you mentioned, `Condition` can be viewed as a pattern, or, pattern-buiding block, it does not surprise me that it behaves in the special way in the context of the pattern-matching. But I think that the source of this behavior is not in `Condition`, but in the pattern-matcher, into which `Condition` must be wired pretty deeply. When the pattern-matcher sees a rule with `Condition`, it evaluates and matches that rule in a special way. The fact that `Condition` does keep the test code unevaluated, does not mean that it is actually the function that eventually evaluates it -  ...

Comment: [2/2] ... rather, it may be a top-level container, that passes that code to some lower-level functionality that actually does the checks. Some analysis in my answer I linked above seems to suggest that this is indeed the case, and the actual heads used for checks are `RuleCondition` and `$ConditionHold`. The evaluations in `Condition` are induced by the pattern-matcher, and are sub-evaluations from the point of view of the main evaluation process for the original expression.  `Condition` taken standalone may behave completely differently, and that does not violate the evaluation rules.

Comment: @Leonid. Many thanks for your further reference and your comments. It will give me a lot to study the next days ... Glad to hear that this behaviour is not simple to explain.

Comment: Glad it you found it helpful. This is certainly one of the things that I wish to have better understood myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was somewhat too long for a comment. Not sure it answers the question but it might give a way of thinking about the elusive handling of `Condition` that proves helpful.

The behavior in question is fairly well documented (I think people know this, I just wanted to state it for the record). The general idea to `RuleDelayed` is that it fires on a match and delivers its rhs. The devil in the details can be broken into two questions. (1) What comprises a match? (2) What is the evaluation of the rhs?

When `Condition` is present on the rhs we do get into some murky semantics issues. The gist is that it is part of what determines whether there is a match, which is to say that the lhs alone does not suffice (I believe this is the only exception to the general rule that the lhs determines a match). As for what is the evaluated rhs, if the `Condition` is `True` then the rhs is what preceded that condition. If it is not `True` then the issue is moot because the delayed rule is not going to fire. Which is the point of having this construct to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for this illuminating and helpful comment. A consequence of your explanation is that a match for Rule is not automatically a match for RuleDelayed, and that the second argument of Rule and of RuleDelayed may be evaluated differently. This surprises me, but it answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, both

```
FullForm@Hold[lhs /. lhs :> (rhs /; test)]
```

and

```
FullForm@Hold[lhs /. lhs :> rhs /; test]
```

yield the same:

```
Hold[Replace[lhs,RuleDelayed[lhs, Condition[rhs,test]]]]
```

and this `Replace` evaluates as the documentation says it does. I think you misunderstand `Condition` as an `If` construct that evaluates to something on its own. But it seems to me that `Condition` is closely tied to `ReplaceAll` as you can make reference to pattern names appearing only in the left hand side of some (delayed) rule. Consider, for example,

```
lhs[1, 2, 3] /. x_ :> (rhs /; (x > 2))]
```

(`lhs[1, 2, rhs]`) and its `FullForm`.

On the other hand, you can "switch-off and on" the condition by typing

```
Condition@@(lhs/.lhs:>NoCondition[rhs,True])
```

Im not sure if that answers your question, though. (Are you asking out of curiosity or do you have some application in mind, where you would need the `ReplaceAll` to return expressions with head `Condition`?)

Comment: Yes, as you observed as in my question, in both situations we have a RuleDelayed with a right hand side Condition[rhs, test]. But this ReplaceAll does NOT evaluate as the documentation says it does. When it did, the result had to be Condition[rhs, test] (Replace e.g. Condition with condition to see the difference.) It seems that when we have a Condition in the second argument of RuleDelayed (not Rule!), this rule is used in a non standard way, and that is what my question is about. Despite the fact that I do not understand it, I have no problems in using it.