# How to use `RuleDelayed`?

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I get what I expect from the following code

```
Replace[{a, b, c}, b_ -> (w /; x > b), {1}]
(* {w /; x > a, w /; x > b, w /; x > c} *)
```

However, when I change `Rule` to `RuleDelayed`, then I get a different result

```
Replace[{a, b, c}, b_ :> (w /; x > b), {1}]
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

I would expect that if the `Condition` was part of the pattern `b_ /; x > b :> w`, but why does `Condition` condition the replacement when it is in the replacement expression?

How to prevent `Condition` from conditioning when it is part of the replacement expression in `RuleDelayed`?

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104772/20253) helpful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first case, the one with [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html), is actually the peculiar result.  [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) is a special pattern-matching operator and does not normally remain verbatim in a replacement but rather affects the replacement itself.

The tutorial [Putting Constraints on Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PuttingConstraintsOnPatterns.html) says, emphasis mine:

> You can use /; on whole definitions and transformation rules, as well as on individual patterns. In general, you can put /;condition at the end of any := definition or :> rule to tell the Wolfram Language that the definition or rule applies only when the specified condition holds. **Note that /; conditions should not usually be put at the end of
>   = definitions or -> rules, since they will then be evaluated immediately,** as discussed in ["Immediate and Delayed Definitions"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html).

Consider these examples using [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) as proxy for [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) and [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) for the sake of convenience.

```
f[x_]  = "yes" /; x > 3;
g[x_] := "yes" /; x > 3;
ff[x_] /; x > 3  = "yes";
gg[x_] /; x > 3 := "yes";

Array[f, 5]
Array[g, 5]
Array[ff, 5]
Array[gg, 5]
```

> ```
> {"yes" /; 1 > 3, "yes" /; 2 > 3, "yes" /; 3 > 3, "yes" /; 4 > 3, "yes" /; 5 > 3}
>
> {g[1], g[2], g[3], "yes", "yes"}
>
> {ff[1], ff[2], ff[3], "yes", "yes"}
>
> {gg[1], gg[2], gg[3], "yes", "yes"}
> ```

Note that in all but the first function `f` it is recognized that the pattern does not match e.g. `g[2]` and the rule is not applied.

It may be in your case that `Rule` is actually the tool you want, or you may need to make `Condition` appear inert to the pattern matcher in some way, e.g.

```
h[x_] := Condition @@ Hold["yes", x > 3]

Array[h, 5]
```

> ```
> {"yes" /; 1 > 3, "yes" /; 2 > 3, "yes" /; 3 > 3, "yes" /; 4 > 3, "yes" /; 5 > 3}
> ```

Because `Condition` has [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) your initial use of `Rule` is "safe" in that the pattern variable `b` is protected from global assignments, therefore **I recommend that you continue using `->` if this is representative of your application,** i.e. `Condition` is the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of the RHS of the rule.  If it is *not* your problem (when using `:>` or `:=`) goes away because the pattern matcher does not see it:

```
f2[x_] := {2 x /; x > 3}    (* RHS Head is List rather than Condition *)

Array[f2, 5]
```

> ```
> {{2 /; 1 > 3}, {4 /; 2 > 3}, {6 /; 3 > 3}, {8 /; 4 > 3}, {10 /; 5 > 3}}
> ```

That head may be [`Identity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity.html) which in normal evaluation disappears, leaving only the verbatim `Condition` expression.  Applied to your original example:

```
Replace[{a, b, c}, b_ :> Identity[w /; x > b], {1}]
```

> ```
> {w /; x > a, w /; x > b, w /; x > c}
> ```

*However* I would not recommend this as it will not interact "well" with held expressions.  Compare:

```
Replace[Hold[a, b, c], b_ :> Identity[w /; x > b], {1}]

Replace[Hold[a, b, c], b_ -> (w /; x > b), {1}]
```

> ```
> Hold[Identity[w /; x > a], Identity[w /; x > b], Identity[w /; x > c]]
>
> Hold[w /; x > a, w /; x > b, w /; x > c]
> ```