# Replace variable with value prior to evaluating NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, hold

The title says it all. Reading posts such as [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression) however, I'm not seeing how to do this. This is the simplest example that can show my problem.

```
f = c/x;
a = a1;
b = b1;
NIntegrate[f, {x, a, b}] /. {a1 -> 1, b1 -> 4, c -> 2}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to make the substitution in both the function and limits before `NIntegrate`. Simple example:

```
f = c/x;
NIntegrate[f /. #, {x, a, b} /. #] & @ {a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Holding `NIntegrate` `Unevaluted` also works.

```
Unevaluated[NIntegrate[f, {x, a, b}]] /. {a -> 1, b -> 4, f -> 2/x}
(* 2.77259 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe little  odd method:

```
g[f, {x, a, b}] /. {a1 -> 1, b1 -> 4, c -> 2, g -> NIntegrate}
```