# Understanding why NIntegrate requires explicit substitution of variables in argument

Tags: numerical-integration

The problem that leads me here begins with a quantity I have previously defined, let's call it `test`, that has many other quantities in its definition. When evaluated, `test` is an expression that includes two variables, let's call them `k` and `x`. A MWE would be

```
test = kx;
```

I wish to create a function of `k` that includes a NIntegration of `test` over `x` with limits that involve `k`. An example would be

```
testint[k_] := NIntegrate[test, {x, k, 2k}];
```

Evaluating this for some `k` , say `k = .1`, returns an error:

```
>>testint[.1]

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand k x has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.1,0.2}}.

NIntegrate[k x, {x, 0.1, 0.2}]
```

However, if I define `testint` using a temporary variable and perform a replacement in the argument of `NIntegrate` , then it computes fine:

```
>>testint[k1_] := NIntegrate[test/.k->k1, {x, k1, 2k1}];
>>testint[.1]
0.0015
```

I found this answer, which led me to try the explicit substitution: [Replace variable with value prior to evaluating NIntegrate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110887/replace-variable-with-value-prior-to-evaluating-nintegrate)
Another answer addresses the order of `NIntegrate` with the help of the `?NumericQ` pattern check: [How do I prevent NIntegrate::inumr errors within other functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/how-do-i-prevent-nintegrateinumr-errors-within-other-functions)

My question is **Why does `NIntegrate` require this explicit substitution in order to compute?**

As a test, I even tried removing `NIntegrate`s `HoldAll` attribute thinking that would force the evaluation of `test` before the integration. It did, but not soon enough to help.

```
>>test = k x;
>>ClearAttributes[NIntegrate, HoldAll]
>>testint[k_] := NIntegrate[testin, {x, k, 2 k}];
>>testint[.1]//Trace

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand k x has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.1,0.2}}.

{testint[0.1], NIntegrate[test, {x, 0.1, 2 0.1}], {test, k x}, {{2 0.1, 0.2}, {x, 0.1, 0.2}}, NIntegrate[k x, {x, 0.1, 0.2}], {{x} =., {x =.}, {x =., Null}, {Null}}, {x =., Null}, ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) `kx` is not the same as `k*x` or `k x` (note space). (2) The evaluation might be less noisy if you define `testint[k_?NumericQ] := ...` Alternatively could do `NIntegrate[...,Method->{"SymbolicProcessing"->None}]` in case that's the cause of the messages (I have not tested this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition `testint[k_] := NIntegrate[test, {x, k, 2k}];` replaces only the `k` that appear in the literal code.  Thus `testint[0.1]` returns the expression

```
NIntegrate[test, {x, 0.1, 2*0.1}]
```

Only then is `test` evaluated, at which point the integrand becomes `k x`, after `testint[0.1]` is done and all the instances of `k` have been replaced (that are going to be replaced).  Thus the trouble is in how `testint` and `test` are defined, not with `NIntegrate` per se.

This can be observed in the output of `Trace[]`:

```
testint[0.1] // Trace
```

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the argument `k` to `testint` is localized and the `k` in  `test` is ``Global` ``, but that is rather a half-explanation, since the localization mechanism makes a difference.  `NIntegrate` localizes `x` effectively with `Block`, a different mechanism.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of the OP's code is. One fix is to make dependencies explicit: `ClearAll[test]; test[k_, x_] := k*x`.