# Can I release a pattern without releasing the whole held expression?

Tags: pattern-matching, hold

I would like to release only the rules in an expression that held. Is that possible?

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, expr];
expr = HoldForm[a = 2 b c /. c -> 5]
(* a=2 b c/. c->5 *)
```

I can release the whole expression:

```
ReleaseHold@expr
(* 10 b *)
```

But I would like to do this:

```
ReleasePattern@expr
(* a = 10 b *)
```

Unfortunately there is no ReleasePattern command. Is it possible to do this by other means?

Comment: You seem to really need [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression). Borderline duplicate, but I hesitate to claim that it is full dupe. Let's see what others think.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I too am on the fence about whether this one is a duplicate.  Whoops, just slid onto one side of the fence... :)

Comment: @WReach Actually, IMO it's great that you did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can define a helper function that will release any component of a held expression that matches a particular pattern:

```
releaseHeldMatches[patt_] := ReplaceAll[p:patt :> RuleCondition[p]]
```

We can then use it to release the `ReplaceAll` that appears in the expression from the question:

```
expr // releaseHeldMatches[_ReplaceAll]
(* HoldForm[a = 10 b] *)
```

The function *releasePattern* from the question can then be defined thus:

```
releasePattern = releaseHeldMatches[_ReplaceAll];

expr // releasePattern
(* HoldForm[a = 10 b] *)
```

Both of these work upon some part of the expression that matches a pattern.  Perhaps we would like to release a part found at a particular index instead:

```
releaseAt[i__][expr_] := ReplacePart[expr, {i} -> expr[[i]]]

expr // releaseAt[1, 2]
(* HoldForm[a = 10 b] *)
```

*Note: one might object to `releaseHeldMatches` operating upon level zero of the held expression, or lament that extracted subexpressions may be held in their own right.  I purposely choose not to worry about either of these contingencies, but should one care:*

```
releaseHeldMatchesPedantic[patt_, expr_] :=
    Replace[expr, p: patt :> RuleCondition[ReleaseHold[p]], {1, Infinity}]
releaseHeldMatchesPedantic[patt_][expr_] :=
    releaseHeldMatchesPedantic[patt, expr]
```

Comment: Having specialized and detailed answer here is probably much better than just announcing this as a dupe. +1 as always.

Comment: @WReach - Thanks for the answer. I had trouble making releaseAt work with a different expression:
 `expr2=(f[a+2 b c]==g[a,c])/. c->5;`
Changing the arguments from `[1,2]` to several other alternatives did not work. 
Also, is there a way to make `releasePatterns` work with selected patterns like `c->5`, leaving others unevaluated?

Comment: @WReach - Sorry, I forgot the HoldForm around the code for expr2 in my previous comment.

Comment: If we have `expr3 = HoldForm[(f[a+2 b c] /. a -> 2) == (g[a,c]/. c -> 5)]` and define `releaseCOnly = releaseHeldMatches[HoldPattern[_ /. c-> 5]];`, then we can write `expr3 // releaseCOnly` to get `HoldForm[(f[a + 2*b*c] /. a -> 2) == g[a, 5]]`.