# Apply function to nested associations

Tags: associations

This seems like it should be easy but I am trying to concisely enhance some nested associations with Mathematica objects (e.g., convert things to matrices, etc) but I'm having a bit of difficulty with nested items. In my case I want to go through an arbitrarily nested association and anywhere there is a key == 'somevalue' (correlation below) I want to replace its value with the result. KeyValueMap almost does the trick (see below). But it doesn't take a levelspec, I'm wondering if someone can show me how you get around this since some functions take levelspecs and some don't. Example code:

```
test = <| "name" -> "foo", "correlation" -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} , 
"descendants" -> <| "name" -> "bar", "correlation" -> {{12, 13}, {20, 22}}|> |>;
KeyValueMap[If[#1 == "correlation", #1 -> MatrixForm[#2], #1 -> #2] &, test]
```

Expected output would have both correlations formatted as matrices, but as you can guess the descendant one is missed with the code as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Replace[]` on `Association`s, but it's sort of weird because it tries to treat keys transparently. If your `Replace` patterns include association markers (`<| |>`), then `Replace` can be convinced to care about keys, but the tricky part there is matching against *every* rule within an association.

It turns out that you can get past all of this and coax Mathematica into doing what you want with a clever pattern.

```
Replace[test, <|a___, "correlation" -> x_, b___|> :>
  <|a, "correlation" -> MatrixForm[x], b|>, All]
```

We're asking `Replace` to match all associations that have a `"correlation"` rule anywhere inside (using the pattern `<|a___, "correlation" -> x_, b___|>`) at `All` nesting levels within your association.

The `a___` (three underscores) and `b___` parts capture everything within the `Association` before or after the `"correlation"` rule. The part after the `:>` in the replace rule drops your transformed middle part (captured by `x`) in between what was captured as `a` and `b`.

Comment: WReach's and yours both work. I like that this one seems to be the most concise, but I don't quite understand it. Do you think you could add a little more explanation (e.g., what is 'a' doing here?). Thank you!

Comment: @Dan, he could have renamed a -> pre and b -> post. That's a pattern expression used so "correlation" can appear anywhere in the `Association`, at the beginning, in the middle, or at end.

Comment: @Dan, I added more explanation above.

Comment: @sblom, do you know why levelspec `All` matches both "correlation" `Keys` but numerical levelspec 1 matches only the {{12,13},{20,22}} value, not the first? Is there a numerical levelspec that matches both?

Comment: @alancalvitti, I'm not terribly good at levelspecs, but I think what makes a numeric one not work here is that we need level 0 (if you provide a number, it assumes you intend to skip level `0`) all the way to the inner-most level. I suppose `{0,-1}` would work if that counts as numeric for purposes of your question?

Comment: @sblom, level 0 matches `Head` expression

Comment: That totally clicked. I turned around and used variations on this in probably 3 other different kinds of problems today. Thanks so much!

Comment: @alancalvitti _Part_ 0 refers to the head of an expression.  _Level_ 0 refers to the whole expression.  The documentation for `Replace` tells us that a number _n_ matches levels 1 through _n_ whereas _All_ matches all levels including zero.

Answer (score 5):

Any occurrence of the association key `"correlation"` at any depth of an expression will have a position index that matches the pattern `{___, Key["correlation"]}`.  We can use either `MapIndexed` or `ReplacePart` to exploit this observation and apply a function of our choosing at such positions (e.g., `MatrixForm`):

```
MapIndexed[
  #2 /.  {{___, Key["correlation"]} :> MatrixForm[#], _ -> #} &
, test
, -1
]
```

[image: result]

```
ReplacePart[
  test
, i : {___, Key["correlation"]} :> RuleCondition @ MatrixForm @ Extract[test, i]
]
```

[image: result]

`RuleCondition` is used in the latter case because an association value is a held context.  See [(29319)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/142) for details of this method.

Comment: If anyone at WRI is listening, it might be useful if there were a "vertical" level-spanning notation that matched any number of levels, e.g. `expr[[SpanLevels, Key["x"]]]` or `expr // Query[SpanLevels, "x"]`.  This would be an analog to the XQuery/XPath `//` operator.

Comment: Thank you so much for these answers. They also worked for me and I'm sure I will find opportunities to use these approaches as well.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) if you don't mind explicitly specifying the [`Key`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Key.html)s.

```
MapAt[MatrixForm, test, {{"correlation"}, {"descendants", "correlation"}}]
```

If `"descendants"` contains a list of [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)s then `{"descendants", All, "correlation"}` instead.

Hope this helps.