# Evaluate an expression with variable values stored in the form "variable name" + val

Tags: programming, symbols

Consider an expression `exp = a^2 + b + c` which has variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, and its values are stored in `aval = 1`, `bval = 2`, and `cval = 3`.

If `cval` is not given I would like the expression to get evaluated to `3 + c`.

The function I have written is:

```
rulesVal[exp_] := 
 Cases[Variables@exp, 
  x_ /; Head[x] == Symbol :> (x -> Symbol[ToString[x] <> "val"])]

toVal[exp_] := exp /. rulesVal[exp]
```

When I input `a^2 + b + c` to `toVal` function, I get `3 + cval`.

How do I get `3 + c`?

Comment: Have you seen `ValueQ`?

Comment: The typical way this is written in MMA is `exp=a^2+b+c` and `exp/.{a->1,b->2}` which yields `3+c`

Comment: @ Manuel, I know that. That is good enough for a small expression. However, when it contains so many variables in an expression, it becomes difficult to see which variables are in the expression, and correspondingly writing a rule for that variable.

Comment: BTW, did you generate the assignments `aval = 1` etc., or are they given to you in a data file or something? I ask because there are better ways to manage  such data. `val[x_] := x` and then `val[a] = 1; val[b] = 2`; usage something like `exp /. Thread[# -> val /@ #]&@Variables[exp]`. Or similarly with `Association`.

Comment: @ Michael E2, I tried using `ValueQ` in the following way,
`rulesVal[exp_] := 
  If[ValueQ[
      Symbol[ToString[#] <> "val"]], (# -> 
       Symbol[ToString[#] <> "val"]), # -> #] & /@ (Variables@exp);`

`toVal[exp_] := exp /. rulesVal[exp];`

When evaluating toVal[exp], it gives an error which says "OwnValues::sym: Argument Symbol[ToString[a]<>val] at position 1 is expected to be a symbol."

Comment: @MichaelE2, thank you. I like the simple way you proposed.  
I wrote those assignments and there are around 50 of such assignments. If there is no other way, then I will adapt your way.

Comment: Yes, I reckon `ValuesQ` is perhaps not so easy because it is `HoldAll`: it's tricky to pass it the unevaluated symbol. If the assignments are all numeric values, try `NumericQ`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, it works with NumericQ. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suppose you can answer your own question, then? (It is quite ok. You may still get better answers from others.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Direct solution

```
aval = 1;
bval = 2;
cval =.;

exp = a^2 + b + c;

rule =
 s_Symbol :>
  With[{sv = ToHeldExpression[ToString[s] <> "val"]},
    ReleaseHold[sv] /; ValueQ @@ sv
  ];

exp /. rule
```

> ```
> 3 + c
> ```

Reference:

- [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121)

#### Recommended alternative

However this (the method above) really is a poor way to approach this problem in my opinion.

It should not really be difficult to make a [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) list (as proposed by  [Manuel --Moe-- G](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13738/manuel-moe-g)).  If you use an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) it is even easier:

```
asc = <||>;
asc[a] = 1;
asc[b] = 2;

exp = a^2 + b + c;

exp /. asc
```

> ```
> 3 + c
> ```

If you are using an older version of *Mathematica* that does not have Associations then a [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) definition ([indexed object](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html)) as [Michael](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) proposed is a good alternative:

```
val[a] = 1;
val[b] = 2;

exp = a^2 + b + c;

exp /. s_Symbol /; ValueQ[val[s]] :> val[s]
```

> ```
> 3 + c
> ```