# How do I defer evaluate in conditional expressions when the arguments are list elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

I'm trying to take a conditional expression like "3 > 1" as an argument for a function but without its evaluation before being passed.  HoldForm works fine in situations like this:

```
*In[1]:=*  3 > 1

*Out[1]=*  True


*In[2]:=*  3 > 1 // HoldForm

*Out[2]=*  3 > 1
```

However, it doesn't work if I use lists....

```
*In[3]:=* a = {3, 2, 1};
b = {1, 2, 3};

*In[4]:=* a[[1]] > b[[1]]

*Out[4]=*  True

*In[5]:=* a[[1]] > b[[1]] // HoldForm

*Out[5]=* a[[1]] > b[[1]]
```

I would like to have '3 > 1' as my output for Out[5]. Using Evaluate[a[[1]]], etc., does not work.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm trying to take a conditional expression like "3 > 1" as an argument for a function but without its evaluation before being passed"  -- that sounds like you need a hold Attribute on your function, e.g. [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html).

For your last example you appear to want a way to evaluate [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) but keep [`Greater`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Greater.html) unevaluated.  If you are using *Mathematica* 10 or later [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) may be a good choice:

```
a = {3, 2, 1};
b = {1, 2, 3};

SetAttributes[f1, HoldFirst]

f1[bool_] := Inactivate[bool, Greater | Less | GreaterEqual | LessEqual | Inequality]


f1[a[[1]] > b[[1]]]

FullForm[%]
```

> ```
> 3 > 1
>
> Inactive[Greater][3,1]
> ```

Another approach is to use [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and specifically evaluate [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
SetAttributes[f2, HoldFirst]
f2[bool_] := HoldForm[bool] /. p_Part :> RuleCondition[p]

f2[a[[1]] > b[[1]]]
```

> ```
> 3 > 1   (* HoldForm *)
> ```

For an explanation of `RuleCondition` see:

- [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121)

If you wish to use this output as input that will fully evaluate you can substitute [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) for `HoldForm`.

Comment: @Kendall You're welcome; I am glad I could help.  If this fully satisfies your question please consider [Accepting it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)