# How to pre-evaluate parts of a lambda or a delayed-assigned function?

Tags: expression-manipulation, pure-function

I have an expression which I'd like to evaluate and use as a subexpression of a delayed-assigned expression. But I need it to be evaluated *before* actual assignment, while other parts of the full expression shouldn't be evaluated at this stage. See this simple example.:

```
testFunc[f_] := Evaluate[(5 + x - x)] D[f, x]
```

If I enclose the whole RHS into `Evaluate`, the expression does pre-evaluate, but since `f` doesn't explicitly depend on `x`, the whole expression becomes `0`. OTOH, if done verbatim as above, `Evaluate` has no effect, and `?testFunc` tells me that the RHS wasn't evaluated before assignment.

I've tried some other approaches, like this:

```
testFunc = Evaluate[(5 + x - x)] D[#, x] &
```

or this (hoping that the replacement will actually evaluate its RHS):

```
testFunc = mark[(5 + x - x)] D[#, x] & /. mark[x_] :> Evaluate[x]
```

But these approaches also don't appear to work.

Of course, one way is like

```
With[{expr = 5 + x - x}, testFunc = expr D[#, x] &]
```

, but when there are multiple such `expr` things, this way becomes very hard to follow, especially if it was created from a formula which I just wanted to optimize by pre-evaluation or simplification.

So, what is a good way to achieve pre-evaluation of subexpressions in delayed assignments or lambdas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make your `mark` thing work like this:

```
evalmark = Function[Null, Unevaluated[#] /. mark[x_] :> RuleCondition[x], HoldFirst];

evalmark[
 test1[f_] := mark[5 + x - x] D[f, x];
 test2[f_] := mark[x + x] f^2;
 ]

?test1
?test2
```

> test[f_] := 5 D[f,x]
>
> test2[f_] := (2 x) f^2

Comment: Hmm, what does `RuleCondition` actually do? Does it evaluate the match before it's applied as a replacement?

Comment: @Ruslan, yes exactly. Look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/862) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've missed something obvious (always a possibility), what you want is simple to implement by writing a factory function.

```
Clear[x]; makeF[expr_] = expr D[#, x]&;
```

Then

```
f = makeF[5 + x - x]
```

`5 D[#1, x]&`

```
f[2 x]
```

> `10`

and

```
Module[{y = 3}, g = makeF[5 x + y]]
```

> `(3 + 5 x) D[#1, x]&`

```
g[Sin[x]]
```

> `(3 + 5 x) Cos[x]`

Comment: I think `something * D[f,x]` was just an example. The intention is to replicate the behaviour of `With` but to do it in-place, ie without removing the pre-evaluated terms from the original expression.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
testFunc[f_, expr_] := Module[{localexpr},
   localexpr = expr; (* Evaluates automatically *)
   Print[localexpr];
   Return[localexpr D[f, x]];
   ];

expr = (5 + x - x);
f = 2 x;

testFunc[f, expr]
(* 5
  10 *)
```

The `Print` is only to confirm that `expr` indeed has been evaluated.

Comment: The Evaluate is superfluous.

Comment: You are right, change incorporated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this suggests what I already showed in the OP as the "last resort" solution, not really acceptable.