# KeyValuePattern in matching and replacement in nested associations

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, associations, hold

This case revealed I am missing something in pattern matching and evaluation in case of match, or I can't grasp it due to the busy week I have. Either way, I find this problem interesting for wider audience:

```
asso = <|
    "key" -> <|"a" -> "1", "b" -> Compress@"test"|>
|>
```

**We want to** replace the inner association with uncompressed value from `"b"` key. **The expected result** is:

```
<|"key" -> "test"|>
```

`Association` is `HoldAllComplete` so we will have to use [**Trott-Strzebonski technique or `RuleCondition`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/5478).

**The problem** is it works but throws a message in between:

```
asso /. KeyValuePattern[ {"a" -> "1", "b" -> val_String}] :> With[
    {eval = Uncompress[val]}
  , eval /; True
]
 (*or RuleCondition@Uncompress[val]*)
```

> ```
> Uncompress::argt: Uncompress called with 0 arguments; 1 or 2 arguments are expected.
>
> <|"key" -> "test"|>
> ```

**The question** is, what am I missing? Recent [chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38449864#38449864) confirms that is not obvious.

I have stuff to do so I'm just using **the workaround**:

```
asso /. sub : KeyValuePattern[{"a" -> "1", "b" -> _String}
] :>   RuleCondition @ Uncompress @ sub @ "b"
```

but I don't get the difference that makes it work.

Comment: The `With` code *does not* give the uncompressed output in Open Cloud.  `asso /. KeyValuePattern[{"a" -> "1", "b" -> val_String}] :> RuleCondition @ Uncompress @ val` *does* give the uncompressed output but *also* issues a message.  Which part of this is more interesting to you?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The point is, I want to be comfortable using `KeyValuePattern`. At the moment I'm not. So any insight is on topic. Also, as pointed out I don't see the reason why my workaround works so I'd say the open cloud kernel is closer to me ;)

Comment: The same weird behaviour prevents replacement in this code: `<|0 -> 0, 1 -> 2|> /. KeyValuePattern[{a_ -> b_, c_ -> d_}] :> (1 /; {d} =!= {c})` even though the condition is `True`.

Answer (score 7):

The output of this code in Open Cloud seems to reveal what is happening:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4|> /.
  KeyValuePattern[{"a"->v1_, "b"->v2_, "c"->v3_, "d"->v4_, "x"->v5_}] :> 
    "foo" /; (Print[{v1},{v2},{v3},{v4},{v5}];True)
```

> {1}{}{}{}{}
>
> {1}{2}{}{}{}
>
> {1}{2}{3}{}{}
>
> {1}{2}{3}{4}{}
>
> ```
> <|a->1,b->2,c->3,d->4|>
> ```

So we can see that the expression is incrementally tested for partial matches.

Rather like:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} /. {x__, ___} :> "foo" /; Print[{x}]
```

> {1}
>
> {1,2}
>
> {1,2,3}
>
> {1,2,3,4}
>
> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

This is how we get `Uncompress[]` in your evaluation as `val_String` is given a null (vanishing) match in the first attempt.

Comment: But why partial matches are considered match? And if it is only due to the condition, why this does not leak: `f[x_Real] := Echo[x^2]; 
Hold[{Hold[2.], Hold[3.], Hold["string"]}] /. 
n_Real :> With[{eval = f[n]}, eval /; True]`

Comment: @Kuba I don't know; this is the first time I have looked at `KeyValuePattern`.  I presume it is part of `KeyValuePattern`'s design, perhaps necessitated by its unusual matching behavior.

Comment: My claim is that either both leak (KeyValuePattern and the example from the comment) or neither. Otherwise this inconsistency is more than a design choice. This or I still miss something.

Comment: @Kuba But `KeyValuePattern` does not work like a simple `_` pattern.  It specifically allows things like `MatchQ[<|a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3|>, KeyValuePattern[b -> 2]]` (True) which implies `___`-like aspects.

Comment: This too but it does not leak: `Hold[{{a -> 1, b -> "string", c -> 3}, {a -> 1, b -> 2,     c -> 3}}] /. {___, b -> i_Integer, ___} :>   With[{eval = Echo[i^2]}, eval /; True]`

Comment: @Kuba But I think `KeyValuePattern` is nonstandard, like `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue`, and may display behavior that is not precisely replicable with other pattern expressions.  I am not attempting to provide an explanation for the design, merely to illustrate its present behavior.  I would have to have much greater familiarity with this functionality before I could guess the designers intent.

Comment: Accepting its special design, I feel it needs more explanation in documentation. Back to the case, what makes my workaround different?

Comment: @Kuba Oh, I agree, the documentation is insufficient.  Your work-around does not use the pattern `val_` so there is no null pattern to disappear within `Uncompress` and cause the message?

Comment: Yes but if there is matched 'b'-less association then we should get an error like `Uncompress[<|"a" -> 1|>["b"]]`. Have to go now, will have busy weekend so I may not reply asap in following days. Have a nice weekend and thanks for help.

Comment: @Kuba Oh, good point, let me look at that.  I hope your busy weekend is good not bad! :-)

Comment: @Kuba It looks like the complete pattern `sub` only fires *after* a final match is determined, while the Condition is part of the candidate (attempted match) process.

Comment: This answer clearly addresses the question, but it seems I need more. Like, shouldn't a pattern be predictable? Is KeyValuePattern more than a pattern? How can we classify patterns then? Such case is a clear case that something is not ok.

Comment: @Kuba I understand.  You'll get no pressure to Accept this from me!  Since I don't have `KeyValuePattern` in the version I use I think someone else will be better qualified to respond to these concerns.  My answer is only one step in that process.

Comment: Maybe I should ask another question about the big picture of patterns? This feels like a closed one and I don't want to change it too much.

Comment: @Kuba I don't have a recommendation.  I think KeyValuePattern is the unusual object so widening this to patterns in general may not help, but I also understand (and appreciate) not changing a question too much.  I feel like what we are missing is a canonical explanation of how KeyValuePattern actually operates.  I *guess* that it has or acts like a longer internal pattern form, perhaps a head with Attributes, etc., and this is specially applied to internal `Association` data.