# Evaluate Only Part of a Function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, replacement, symbolic

I have a list of functions, each containing none or more of the functions `Plus`, `Times`, `Subtract` and `Divide`. They could be in any arrangement and with any numbers. This is one such example.

```
HoldForm[Plus[3+Times[7,Subtract[9,Plus[4,5]],Divide[29,Subtract[4,3]]]]]*
```

*There is an error here,* The above should read: `Plus[3,Times[7`

The numbers can be any positive integer. I need to calculate just the `Divide` and `Subtract` functions to find out if they evaluate to 1 or 0 respectively as I consider functions in the list that have this property trivial and I want to filter them out.

I am somewhat a beginner with Wolfram/Mathematica code and I have been attempting to extract the `Divide` and `Subtract` parts as a list and then calculating just them parts but so-far my attempts at solving this have been totally unfruitful, partly because I can't know beforehand where the `Divide` or `Subtract` functions are in the function or how deep they will be.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**Edit:** Just to help clarify what I am trying to achieve. I have a list of functions such as

`{HoldForm[Plus[3,Times[7,Subtract[9,Plus[4,5]],Divide[29,Subtract[4,3]]]]],
HoldForm[Plus[7,Times[2,Divide[16,Subtract[9,Plus[4,1]]]]]],
HoldForm[Plus[3,Times[7,9],29]]}`

I need to remove the first element from the list because it is a function that divides by 1 (and subtracts 0), making is only trivially different from the 3rd element of the list. After removing the first function I want to display the output like this

{$7+2 \frac{16}{9-(4+1)}$,$3+7\times 9+29$}

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Can you please put any code snippets in code blocks to improve the readability of the question?

Comment: What would be a result of `Subtract[9,Plus[4,5]]` if `Plus` is not included in your list?

Comment: In my example, the whole thing should be removed from my list of functions. This is because `Subtract[9,Plus[4,5]]` will evaluate to 0 and so it means the example is trivial as there will be another function in the list that is the same except it won't `Subtract[0]`

Comment: In that case why don't you just evaluate the whole thing and say that the result is 3?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Szabolcs. Advice appreciated. I have looked up how to do it and will ensure I follow your advice going forward.

Comment: Also, are you aware that in Mathematica `-` and `/` are not represented with `Subtract` and `Divide`? Thus unless you explicitly typed in `Subtract`/`Divide`, kglr's answer (which I would also have suggested otherwise) will not work.

Comment: I want to display the function unevaluated for the user, but only if the output doesn't contain anything that just means subtract nothing or divide by one

Comment: Szabolics, I think that is my bad writing skills, I have edited the question to remove the /

Comment: `HoldForm[Plus[3+Times[7,Subtract[9,Plus[4,5]],Divide[29,Subtract[4,3]]]]]` should be rejected from my list but `HoldForm[Plus[7,Times[2,Divide[16,Subtract[9,Plus[4,1]]]]]]` should not.

Comment: No, that / was not confusing. Let me rephrase: do you work with (1) expressions such as `1/(2+3)` or (2) expression like `Divide[1, 2+3]`? Are you aware that these are not the same thing? Do you *really* work with the specific function `Divide`, or do you work with *division* in general, which may be represented in a different way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83115/discussion-between-redpython-and-szabolcs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Selecting from a list expressions those that do not contain subexpressions ***that divide by 1 or subtract 0***:

```
list = {HoldForm[Plus[3, Times[7, Subtract[9, Plus[4, 5]], Divide[29, Subtract[4, 3]]]]],
   HoldForm[Plus[7, Times[2, Divide[16, Subtract[9, Plus[4, 1]]]]]],
   HoldForm[Plus[3, Times[7, 9], 29]]};

condition = FreeQ[#, (s_Subtract /; s == 0) | (d_Divide /; d == 1),  ∞] &;
Select[list, condition]
```

> {7 + 2 16/(9 - (4 + 1)), 3 + 7 9 + 29}

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
exp = Inactivate[Plus[3, Times[7, Subtract[9, Plus[4, 5]], Divide[29, Subtract[4, 3]]]]];
Activate[exp, Divide | Subtract]
```

> 3 + 7*(9 - (4 + 5))*29

An alternative way to evaluate completely subexpressions with head `Divide` or `Subtract`
using `RuleCondition` (from [WReach's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/125) in the q/a linked in Sjoerd's answer):

```
HoldForm[Plus[3, Times[7, Subtract[9, Plus[4, 5]], Divide[29, Subtract[4, 3]]]]] /. 
    e : _Subtract | _Divide :> RuleCondition[e]
```

> 3 + 7 0 29

Answer (score 6):

The answer of kglr works if you only want to do the evaluations associated with `Divide` and `Subtract`. If instead you want every subexpression with these head to evaluate completely, use the following trick:

```
Hold[
  Plus[
   3 + Times[7, Subtract[9, Plus[4, 5]], 
     Divide[29, Subtract[4, 3]]]]
] /. {
   expr : (_Divide | _Subtract) :> With[{x = expr}, x /; True]
}
```

See also the following answer:

[Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression)