# Condition in SparseArray does not check the condition for some matrix elements

Tags: pattern-matching, conditional, sparse-arrays

Consider the following MWE:

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[1]] == 0) :> 1}, {4, 4}]
```

This should give a $4\times 4$ matrix in which the first two rows are filled with ones: `IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[1]] == 0` checks that the first digit of the binary decomposition of $i-1$ is $0$, which happens for $i=1$ and $i=2$.
If I actually run the above code, in v11.3, I instead get a matrix in which only the first row is filled with ones.

If I instead use

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[1]] == 1) :> 1}, {4, 4}]
```

in which I'm asking for the first digit of the binary decomposition to equal $1$, I get a zero matrix.

Funnily enough, If I instead ask for the *second* digits of the binary decomposition to be something, everything works correctly:

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[2]] == 0) :> 1}, {4, 4}]
```

gives first and third nonzero rows.

Something I've noticed by running trace on the first form is that at some point `i` seems to be set to some value *before* the actual checks on the matrix elements happen:

[image]

This doesn't happen in the working examples.
Does anyone understand why this happens?

---

It's also worth noting that I've tried to make the examples even simpler by using one-dimensional "matrices":

```
SparseArray[{i_ /; (IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[2]] == 0) :> 1}, 4]
```

This gives the correct results, but also strange errors, which using the trace shows some weird stuff going on (the `i` is replaced sometimes with a list and sometimes with an integer). This behaviour is solved by using `i_Integer` as condition, so I don't know if this behaviour is related to the other one.

Comment: It seems to me the expression test is firing too quickly in this specific case. When `SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (Echo[{i, j}]; (IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[1]] == 0)) :> 1}, {4, 4}]` is evaluated, only entries in the first row show up, while in the equivalent `SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; (Echo[{i, j}]; (BitGet[i - 1, 1] == 0)) :> 1}, {4, 4}]`, all entries get checked.

Comment: OTOH, at least `SparseArray[{{i_, j_} :> Block[{}, 1 /; IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[1]] == 0]}, {4, 4}]` and `SparseArray[{{i_, j_} :> RuleCondition[1, IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[1]] == 0]}, {4, 4}]` work. (See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317) for more details.)

Answer (score 2):

The second syntax example at the top of the documentation of [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) indicates to me that the test should be placed *after* the `RuleDelayed`. When you do that, it works:

```
SparseArray[{{i_, j_} :> 1 /; IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2][[1]] == 0}, {4, 4}] // Normal
(* Out: {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

---

@glS is on to something odd though. Look at the following attempts at comparing to zero. There should be no precision issues here to trip up `Equal`, since the result from `IntegerDigits` is an arbitrary-precision integer:

```
Table[
 Normal@
  SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; isZero@First@IntegerDigits[i - 1, 2, 2] -> 1}, {4, 4}],
 {isZero, {PossibleZeroQ, (SameQ[#, 0] &), (Equal[#, 0] &), EqualTo[0]}}
]

(* Out:
{{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, (* works as expected *)
 {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, (* works as expected *)
 {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, (* fails *)
 {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}  (* fails *)
}
*)
```

Comment: @glS Yes, but that's `Rule`, not `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: does it? In the documentation of `SparseArray`, under basic examples, I have the following: `s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -2, {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> 1}, {5, 5}]`

Comment: that's true, but if you try this example with `Rule` instead of `RuleDelayed`, it still doesn't work

Comment: @glS Yes, I agree that something else is odd here, and that's not all due to `RuleDelayed` etc. See the added portion of my answer.

Comment: ah, even just replacing `==` with `===` makes it work... I really don't know what to make of it. I don't understand where that weird `i=.` command comes from in the `Trace`