# Function definition from a variable (RESTATED)

Tags: function-construction

This is similar to a problem I had earlier.

I have a variable Gj that is related to the nj, for example:

```
Clear[nj]
Gj = If[nj[1] == 0, 0, nj[1] Log[nj[1]/(nj[1] + nj[2] + nj[3])]]
```

I would like to have a way of defining a function `getGj` for a given `Gj`. For the above example, the function would be defined by:

```
getGj[{a_,b_,c_}] := If[a == 0, 0,a Log[a/(a+b+c)]]
```

The closest I have come (thanks, Kuba) is:

```
Gj := If[nj[[1]]==0,0,nj[[1]] Log[nj[[1]]/(nj[[1]]+nj[[2]]+nj[[3]])]];
Unevaluated[getGj[nj_] := Gj;] /. OwnValues[Gj]
```

which works well for an input list with numeric values, but

```
ClearAll[xx,x]
xx=Array[x,3];
getGj[xx]
```

returns

```
If[x[1] == 0, 0, 
{x[1],x[2],x[3]}[[1]] Log[{x[1],x[2],x[3]}[[1]]/({x[1],x[2],x[3]}[[1]] + {x[1],x[2],x[3]}[[2]]+{x[1],x[2],x[3]}[[3]])]]
```

rather than

```
If[x[1] == 0, 0, x[1] Log[x[1]/(x[1]+x[2]+x[3])]]
```

Comment: Restating the question makes answers out of sync which will confuse future readers... About the question, why do you need to have a variable `Gj = If[nj[1] == 0, 0, nj[1] Log[nj[1]/(nj[1] + nj[2] + nj[3])]]`, where does it come from?

Comment: It comes from a thermodynamics program that I am trying to write, and I need to calculate the product of the concentration nj[1] and the log of the activity which is n[1]/(n[1]+n[2]+n[3]), even when n[1] equals zero, in which case the product is zero.      (Should I have started a new question?)

Answer (score 1):

The first element from a list is `nj[[1]]`, not `nj[1]`.

Additionally notice that `Gj` can accidentally evaluate to something you don't expect, here `nj[[1]] == 0` will remain and keep `If` unevaluated but e.g. `TrueQ@nj` will not wait till you provide a value for `nj`.

That is why this is not the best way to create functions.

You could do:

```
ClearAll[getGj, nj, Gj];

Gj := If[ (* := !!!*)
  nj[[1]] == 0, 0, nj[[1]] Log[nj[[1]]/(nj[[1]] + nj[[2]] + nj[[3]])]
];

Unevaluated[getGj[nj_] := Gj;] /. OwnValues[Gj]

getGj[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> -Log[6]
> ```

It is hard to suggest something more handy without a broader context of the question.

Comment: Hello - That works great for numerical values, but I was hoping to also be able to input : xx=Array[x,3];getGj[xx] and obtain If[x[1]==0,0,etc.]. In other words, to have it work for symbolic arrays as well.

Comment: The function I am trying to build is getGj[{a_, b_, c_}] := If[a == 0, 0, a Log[a/(a + b + c)]]; but for general Gj as a function of the nj

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing some subtlety in your code, or outright misunderstanding your intent, but this appears to do the same thing more simply:

```
ClearAll[getGj, nj, Gj, zz, z];

Gj = If[nj[1] == 0, 0, nj[1] Log[nj[1]/(nj[1] + nj[2] + nj[3])]];

getGj[in_] := Block[{nj}, Gj /. nj[i__] :> RuleCondition @ in[[i]] ];

zz = Array[z, 3];
nj[1] = 22;

getGj[zz]
getGj[{1, 2, 3}]
```

> ```
> If[z[1] == 0, 0, z[1] Log[z[1]/(z[1] + z[2] + z[3])]]
>
> -Log[6]
> ```

Reference:

- [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121)

Comment: Another test I use is to set some nj to a numerical value, say nj[1]=22. In the above case, getGj[zz]  and getGj[{1,2,3}] do not return the proper value.

Comment: PS - I add the nj[1]=22 after the function definition.

Comment: @Paul Please see and test the update.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
ClearAll[getGj, nj, Gj, zz, z, a, b, c, x, xx];
Gj = If[nj[1] == 0, 0, nj[1] Log[nj[1]/(nj[1] + nj[2] + nj[3])]];
rul = Table[nj[j] -> Slot[j], {j, 1, 3}]
getGjx = Evaluate[Gj /. rul] &;
xx = Array[x, 3];
getGj[xx_] := Apply[getGjx, xx]
ClearAll[xx]
```

as a test:

```
ClearAll[z]
zz = Array[z, 3];
nj[1]=22;
getGj[zz]
getGj[{1, 2, 3}]
```

yields

```
If[z[1] == 0, 0, z[1] Log[z[1]/(z[1] + z[2] + z[3])]]
-Log[6]
```

as hoped for. Any improvements would be welcome.

(P.S. I don't understand why I cant substitute the expression for getGjx into the definition of getGj.)