# How to Force Evaluation of Derivative in a Pure Function Definition

Tags: functions, evaluation, functional-style, hold, pure-function

Let's say I have a function

```
f1 = #^2 &;
```

I want to calculate its derivative, perform some manipulations and make the result a pure function. I try

```
D[f1[x], x] (*Function[{x}, \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\(f1[x]\)\)]*)
```

So the derivative didn't evaluate. I try forcing it

```
Function[{x}, Evaluate@D[f1[x], x]] (*Function[{x}, 2 x]*)
```

And it works. But let's say I want to additionally manipulate the derivative inside the function so I try

```
Function[{x}, N@Evaluate@D[f1[x], x]] (*Function[{x}, N[Evaluate[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(∂\), \(x\)]\(f1[x]\)\)]]]*)
```

And this doesn't work anymore. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? I also obviously lack understanding of the evaluation logic of such cases, so I will be grateful for explanations or references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's examine the problem as given.  I will consider it as a general code rewriting problem.   We have an expression of the form

```
h[.., f[ Evaluate[g[x]] ],..]     (* or more generally... *)
h[.., f[ Evaluate[g[x]], y],..]  (* etc. *)
```

where `h` is a `HoldAll` function and we'd like to evaluate `g[x]` but not `f[]` to get

```
h[.., f[g0],..]      (* or *)
h[.., f[g0, y],..]
```

where `g0 = g[x]`.  `Evaluate` does not work this way, because `Evaluate[expr]` is evaluated only when it appears ***as*** an argument of `h`; it is not evaluated when it appears ***in*** an argument at a lower level.

For `Evaluate` to do its work, it needs to appear one level higher around `f`:

```
h[.., Evaluate[f[g[x],..]],..]
```

But that yields

```
h[.., f0,..]
```

where `f0 = f[g[x],..]`, which is different that what we said we wanted.  For instance, in this example, `N[]` has no effect:

```
f2 = #^2/2 &;
Function[{x}, Evaluate@N@D[f2[x], x]]
(*  Function[{x}, x]  *)
```

One way to get the code rewritten is to extend the semantics of `Evaluate` with a replacement rule:

```
h[.., f[Evaluate[g[x]],..],..] /.
 e_Evaluate :> RuleCondition[e, True]
```

The OP's example:

```
f1 = #^2 &;
Function[{x}, N@Evaluate@D[f1[x], x]] /.
 e_Evaluate :> RuleCondition[e, True]
(*  Function[{x}, N[2 x]]  *)
```

Note that the rule will result in all expressions `Evaluate[expr]` to be evaluated, even if an expression appears in `HoldComplete` or a function that has the attribute `HoldAllComplete`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is not very clear for me where is HoldAll applied in the initial example. Also, I cannot find documentation for RuleCondition, is there anywhere I can read about it?

Comment: @Ihor You're welcome.   `HoldAll` is found in `Attributes@Function`; in the general scheme at the beginning of the answer, `h` represents `Function` in your question.  I found out about `RuleCondition` here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/4999

Answer (score 7):

```
f1 = #^2 &;
```

`f1'` gives a pure function:

```
df1 = f1'
```

> 2 #1 &

```
df1[2]
```

> 4

Alternatively, you can use [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html):

```
df1b = Derivative[1] @ f1
```

> 2 #1 &

```
df1b[3]
```

> 6

Re *"to additionally manipulate the derivative inside the function"*,  you can use `Composition` to wrap `df1` with desired manipulations:

```
ndf1 = N@*(f1')
```

> N@*(2 #1 &)

```
ndf1[2]
```

> 4.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know why in the specific case I attempted it didn't work?

Comment: @Ihor,   1. `D[f1[x], x]` does give `2x` (version 11.3.0 - Windows 10) (maybe you need to use `ClearAll[f1]` before line that defines `f1`)  and 2. Using  `Evaluate @ N @ D[f1[x],x]` instead of `N @ Evaluate @ D[f1[x],x]` works (This has to do with the `HoldAll` attribute of `Function`; it does not evaluate its arguments unless it sees `Evaluate` as the head of the argument)

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is due in this specific case to [`NHoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldAll.html). Under `Scope` we find both `Derivative` and `Slot`, among many others which also have this attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it seems not to be the reason because, for example, Function[{x}, Sin@Evaluate[D[f1[x], x]]] also doesn't evaluate.

Comment: @Ihor that isn't `N`, though :) I made sure to specify *in this specific case*, but you are correct. It seems to me, here, now, that you are not applying the functions after you define them, as both your examples work once you apply them to something like `x`. The initial example gives `2. x` and this most recent one gives `Sin[2 x]`, when you apply it to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
f1 = #^2 &;
```

derivative

```
f1s = Function[x, f1'[x] // Evaluate]
f1s[u]    (*2 u*)
```

or

```
F1s[u_] := f1'[u]
```