# Generate pattern held by HoldPattern

Tags: pattern-matching, hold

I am trying to match expressions that have factors with certain exponents. For instance, I would like to match as follows

```
expr = a^2 * b^2;
MatchQ[expr, HoldPattern[Times[_^2, _^2]]]
```

This is fine. The problem I want to solve now is, given a list of exponents to generate a pattern that matches any expression which has factors with said exponents. What I tried for the above example is the following

```
exponents = {2, 2};
pattern = With[{list = _^#& /@ exponents}, HoldPattern[Times@@list];
```

But this does not work, since the pattern reads `Times@@{_^2, _^2}` instead of `Times[_^2, _^2]`.

Is there a way to insert the arguments into a `HoldPattern` programatically?

One way I could imagine is that you do something like `f@@(_^#& /@ exponents)` and then replace `f` by `Times`, but I cannot see how to do this while keeping the arguments "unevalutated".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to is to use direct replacement:

```
exponents = {2, 2};

_^# & /@ exponents /. {e__} :> HoldPattern[Times[e]]

(* HoldPattern[_^2 * _^2] *)
```

For more elaborate mechanisms that partially evaluate held expressions, see [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/142).

Comment: +1. I think, this particular method got a name ["injector pattern"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=injector+pattern) on this site.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thank you for the terminology.