# Highlight part of the expression like this

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, display

I want to highlight the coefficient of the polynomial is not ±1, I have tried

```
Factor[x^105 - 1] /. k_ x_^n_ /; Abs[k] > 1 -> Style[k x^n, Red]

HoldForm @@ {Factor[x^105 - 1]} /.  k_ x_^n_ /; Abs[k] > 1 -> Style[k , Red] x^n
```

[image]
These are not the results I want, I hope to get results like this

[image]

It would be better if it could be displayed in traditional format in programmatically
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HoldForm @@ {Factor[x^105 - 1]} /. k_ x_^n_ :> 
  RuleCondition[With[{b = Style[Abs[k], Red]}, 
    If[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[k], -1, 1] HoldForm[b x^n]], Abs[k] > 1]
```

[image]

Use `Highlighted[Abs[k]]` instead of `Style[Abs[k], Red]` to get

[image]

**See also:** [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/125)

**Update:** Displaying in `TraditionalForm`:

```
HoldForm @@ (TraditionalForm /@ {Factor[x^105 - 1]}) /. k_ x_^n_ :>
     RuleCondition[With[{b = Style[Abs[k], 14, Red]}, 
    If[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[k], -1, 1] HoldForm[b x^n]], Abs[k] > 1]
```

[image]

We can get `Highlighted` looks using

```
HoldForm @@ (TraditionalForm /@ {Factor[x^105 - 1]}) /. k_ x_^n_ :>
    RuleCondition[With[{b = Framed[Style[Abs[k], 14], Background -> Yellow, 
       FrameStyle -> None]}, 
    If[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ[k], -1, 1] HoldForm[b x^n]], Abs[k] > 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Well done, can it be displayed in traditional format?

Comment: @expression, please see the update.