# Rename a variable in a pattern by an evaluation

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I wish to take some expression containing instances of `Pattern[]`, and rename the variables of those patterns based on evaluation featuring the variable.

Let's say my renaming function is

```
f[s_Symbol] := Symbol[ SymbolName[s] <> "2" ]
```

which just appends 2 to symbol names:

```
f[a]
>>> a2
```

If I try to replace `Pattern` variables with this function (or any expression), that expression remains unevaluated!

```
a_ /. a :> f[a]
>>> Pattern[ f[a], _ ]
```

I assume `Pattern` holds its first argument.

Naturally my example is strange since simplified; I really intend to replace any symbol (which may or may not be featured in a `Pattern`) which satisifes certain properties.

```
a_ /. s_Symbol /; someTest[s] :> f[s]
>>> Pattern[ f[a], _ ]
```

How can I force `Pattern` to evaluate its first argument *after* my substitution? This may appear like the general question of "how to substitute variables of functions that hold their arguments", but alas, the [documented technique](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/SubstituteValuesOfVariablesInFunctionsThatHoldTheirArguments.html) for that does not seem to apply here:

```
a_ /. a :> With[{x=f[a]}, x]

>>> Pattern[With[{x = f[a]}, x], _]
```

I cannot just insert an `Evaluate` into the RHS of my `DelayedRule` (though that would solve my first hard-coded example), since this just violates the rule delay, and invokes `f[s]`.

**EDIT**

Here's an example to test candidate solutions with:

```
f[s_] := Symbol[ SymbolName[s] <> "2"];

test[s_] := (s =!= Pattern && s =!= Blank)

a_ /. s_Symbol /; test[s] :> f[s]

>>> Pattern[f[a], _]
(* desired output: Pattern[a2, _] *)
```

Comment: "I assume `Pattern` holds its first argument." - `MemberQ[Attributes[Pattern], HoldFirst]` returns `True`, so...

Comment: You definition of `f`  will work if you call `Symbol` with the correct syntax: `Symbol[ SymbolName[s] <>  "2" ] `

Comment: @J.M. so my assumption was correct?

Comment: @DanielHuber no, it won't. That's a typo in my MWE, that isn't relevant to the evaluation; clearly you can see `f[a]` remains unevaluated in my example, despite the definition of `f`...

Comment: Try `a_ /; a > 0/.a :> Unevaluated[Evaluate@f[a]]`

Comment: @RomaLee This is not a solution for the general case (with replace-pattern symbol `s`), as per my mention of using `Evaluate`

Comment: @AntiEarth it works for your test code, could you provide code where it fails?

Comment: @RomaLee there's an example for you to try right there in my question

Comment: f[s_] := Symbol[SymbolName[s] <> "2"];

test[s_] := (s =!= Pattern && s =!= Blank)

a_ /. s_Symbol /; test[s] :> Unevaluated[Evaluate@f[a]]

gives 

a2_

Is it not what you want?

Comment: @RomaLee You're hard-coding `f[a]` (instead of `f[s]`), that is obviously **not** what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluation of the replacing expression can be forced (*at* replacement time) using the undocumented `RuleCondition`, as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression).

```
f[s_] := Symbol[ SymbolName[s] <> "2"];

test[s_] := (s =!= Pattern && s =!= Blank)

a_ /. s_Symbol /; test[s] :> RuleCondition[f[s]]

>>> a2_
```