# ReplaceAll not evaluating the rule delayed function

Tags: replacement, rule

Given

```
records = {<|"Material" -> "FG126", "Batch" -> "0000000009", "CreationDateTime" -> "/Date(1474502400000+0000)/"|>, 
<|"Material" -> "FG126","Batch" -> "0000000011", "CreationDateTime" -> "/Date(1474588800000+0000)/"|>};

records /. (a_String /; 
StringMatchQ[a, "/Date(" ~~ ___ ~~ "+0000)/"] :> StringTake[a, {7, 19}])
```

Returns

```
{<|"Material" -> "FG126", "Batch" -> "0000000009", 
  "CreationDateTime" -> 
   StringTake[
    "/Date(1474502400000+0000)/", {7, 19}]|>, <|"Material" -> "FG126",
   "Batch" -> "0000000011", 
  "CreationDateTime" ->
```

Instead of

```
{<|"Material" -> "FG126", "Batch" -> "0000000009", "CreationDateTime" ->"1474502400000"|>, 
 <|"Material" -> "FG126", "Batch" -> "0000000011", "CreationDateTime" -> "1474588800000"|>}
```

The final desired outcome is actually to get the value at CreationDateTime processed as

```
FromUnixTime[creationDateTime/1000]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap `rhs` in  `lhs :> rhs` with `RuleCondition` to force evaluation of the expression `rhs`:

```
records /. (a_String /; 
   StringMatchQ[a, "/Date(" ~~ ___ ~~ "+0000)/"] :> 
      RuleCondition[StringTake[a, {7, 19}]])
```

> ```
> {<|"Material" -> "FG126", 
>    "Batch" -> "0000000009", 
>    "CreationDateTime" -> "1474502400000"|>,
> <|"Material" -> "FG126", 
>   "Batch" -> "0000000011", 
>   "CreationDateTime" -> "1474588800000"|>}
> ```

Or use `RuleCondition` instead of `Condition (/;)`:

```
records /. a_String :> 
  RuleCondition[StringTake[a, {7, 19}], StringMatchQ[a, "/Date(" ~~ ___ ~~ "+0000)/"] ]
```

> ```
> {<|"Material" -> "FG126", 
>    "Batch" -> "0000000009", 
>    "CreationDateTime" -> "1474502400000"|>,
>  <|"Material" -> "FG126",
>    "Batch" -> "0000000011", 
>    "CreationDateTime" -> "1474588800000"|>}
> ```

**See also:** The answers [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/125).

Answer (score 2):

It works if you take the data out of the association for the replacement.

```
Map[Association, Normal[records] /. (a_String /; StringMatchQ[a,
      "/Date(" ~~ ___ ~~ "+0000)/"] :> StringTake[a, {7, 19}])]
```

> ```
> {<|"Material" -> "FG126", "Batch" -> "0000000009", 
>   "CreationDateTime" -> "1474502400000"|>,
>  <|"Material" -> "FG126", "Batch" -> "0000000011",
>   "CreationDateTime" -> "1474588800000"|>}
> ```