# How to use Through by default on numeric functions?

Tags: code-generation, meta-programming, functional-style

I've used the following code to simulate defining operations between functions:

```
ThroughFunctions[expr_] := expr//.{
x_?NumericQ[___] -> x,
(f_/;MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction])[x___][y___] :> Through[f[x][y]]
}

$Pre = ThroughFunctions;
```

Since it's assigned to $Pre the substitution occurs without having to wrap the expressions in the function ThroughFunctions:

`In[10]:=(Cos^2/(3+Sin))[x]`

`Out[10]=Cos[x]^2/(3+Sin[x])`

The problem with this is that it doesn't work when I try to use it in an expression that delays the evaluation:

`Plot[(Sin + Cos^2)[x], {x, 0, Pi}]`

returns an empty graphic.

Is there a way to implement this in a more robust way so it works better?

Comment: How would you enter `Log[Cos[x]]`, `x + Sin[x]`, and `E^Sin[x]` (or `2^Sin[x]`, `x^x`,...)?

Comment: Setting `Id = Identity` for brevity, I would enter those expression like this:
`Log[Cos][x]`, `(Id+Sin)[x]`, `(E^Sin)[x]`, `(2^Sin)[x]`, `(Id^Id)[x]`

Comment: Would an approach where you define an alias work? For example, you would enter `Log[Cos] alias x` that would look like `Log[Cos] @ x` but would use your evaluation function.

Comment: @CarlWoll That's an ingenious approach. I think that avoids the problem of delayed evaluation. Unfortunately also introduces others problems, since that wouldn't get along with operators (Map, Apply, ...)

Comment: Do you mean want `Map[Sin + Cos, Range[5]]` to give `{Sin[1]+Cos[1],...,Sin[5]+Cos[5]}`? That seems a different problem than rewriting input.  I don't think any `$Pre` method would work on this.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm not sure why, but the $Pre method does work.

Comment: @jjagmath I believe the input (`Map[..]`) is evaluating before the transformation in `ThroughFunctions` is applied, since its arguments are not held. This is the reason `Plot[]` fails: it is evaluated before the replacement. I don't think a robust solution can operate on the expression after it has been evaluated. If you want `(Sin + Cos)[x]` to evaluate to `Sin[x] + Cos[x]` whether it is on input or the result of an intermediate computation, I don't know how that could be done. It could be done with a wrapper like `func[Sin + Cos][x]`, by defining `func` like `ThroughFunctions`.

Answer (score 1):

For the example mentioned in the question, we just need to adjust the evaluation order a bit:

```
$Pre =.
SetAttributes[ThroughFunctions, HoldAll]
ThroughFunctions[expr_] := 
 Hold@expr //. {x_?NumericQ[___] :> 
     x, (f_ /; MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction])[x___][y___] :> 
     RuleCondition@Through[f[x][y]]} // ReleaseHold

$Pre = ThroughFunctions;

Plot[(Sin + Cos^2)[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: There's an evaluation leak: `x = 3; Block[{x}, Plot[(Sin + Cos^2)[x], {x, 0, Pi}]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oops, you're right, and I've no idea how to fix this…

Comment: Yeah, I ran into that myself and found a workaround. But the OP's actual goals seem to be a bit broader, judging from a recent comment. They seem to want this type of evaluation no matter how `(Sin + Cos^2)[x]` arises (e.g. `(Sin + Cos^2) /@ {x}`, `(Sin + Cos^2) @@ {x}`, etc.). I can handle transforming the input, but I don't know how to do it when the expression arises programmatically, in the middle of a computation.

Comment: @xzczd What is RuleCondition? It's undocumented

Comment: @jjagmath Yeah, it's a handy undocumented function for adjusting evaluation order. (A simple example illustrating its effect: `{Hold[1] /. 1 :> 1 + 1, Hold[1] /. 1 :> RuleCondition[1 + 1]}`. ) For more info you may refer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/1871

Comment: @MichaelE2 `x_?NumericQ[___] -> x` should be `x_?NumericQ[___] :> x`, right?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit As long as `x` is not polluted, `->` is not a problem :) . I intentionally choose `->` and `=` instead of `:>` and `:=` when it's possible, because I see so many people abusing `:>` and `:=`. (I even met guys think `=` cannot be used for defining function! )

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I understand that it works if `x` is not polluted, but why would you assume that? `:>` is absolutely the right choice here.

Comment: I agree with @SjoerdSmit. I can't explain why I didn't explain it after my first comment. It's almost certainly what I meant.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit and Michael Oops, I forgot `x` may be polluted afterwards… Edited. Thx for pointing out. (Perhaps I'm tired… )