# ToString with delayed replacement

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I want a `toString` method that replaces each occurrence of `f[x_]`.

```
obj1ToString[x_] := StringRiffle[x, ""];
obj2ToString[y_] := ToString[y /. f[x_] :> "(" <> obj1ToString@x <> ")"];

obj2ToString[g@f[{1, 2, 3}]]
(* "g[(123)]" *)
obj2ToString[f[{1, 2, 3}] &]
(* "(<>obj1ToString[{1, 2, 3}]<>) & " *)
```

As you can see, it doesn't work in all contexts. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the desired output of `obj2ToString[f[{1, 2, 3}] &]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

As @CarlWoll points out, the original solution is unstable - easily breaking for some arguments of `f`. The better solution is to do something like

```
toString[y_]:= ToString[y /. f[x_]:> With[{eval="("<>StringRiffle[x,""]
     <> ")"},eval /; True]];
```

which is based on this thread here: [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression)

### Original

Just turn your whole expression into a string then do your replacement.

```
toString[y_] := StringReplace[ToString[y],"f[" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "]" :> 
    "(" <> StringRiffle[ToExpression@x, ""] <> ")"];
```

Comment: In general, I recommend avoiding approaches that convert to strings and then use string manipulation functions. In particular, using single argument ToString is very bad, consider `toString[f[{1/2}]]`. Your replacement also has issue, e.g., `toString[f[{g[x]}]`. Finally, approaches using ToExpression can be scary if the function can be applied to arbitrary content.

Comment: @CarlWoll, all fair points. Given the OP's definition of `obj1ToString` using `StringRiffle` it is clear they expect the argument of `f` to always be a `List` of symbols. Given what's written, it's unclear what behavior they even want from something like `toString[f[{g[x]}]` (although it's safe to assume `$Failed` isn't it). I suppose I should have waited for their clarification before shooting off this ugly hack of an answer. I agree it's dangerous as written. When OP clarifies what they're looking for I'll improve the answer.