# Different evaluation control inside of `Integrate` than outside of it

Tags: evaluation, hold

I want to keep inside of a integral evaluated after some replacement inside it, but at the same time the integral itself unevaluated.

I start with:

```
int=HoldForm[Integrate[x^n/(x + 1)^(n + 1), {x, 0, 1}]]
```

Output as desired:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{(x+1)^{n+1}} \, dx$$

When I replace `n` with some number I get output as expected:

```
int /. n -> 3
```

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{(x+1)^{3+1}} \, dx$$

But then I want to evaluate the inside of the integral and keep the integral itself unevaluated.

So I tried instead:

```
int = HoldForm[Integrate[Evaluate[x^n/(x + 1)^(n + 1)], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

$$\int_0^1 \text{Evaluate}\left[\frac{x^n}{(x+1)^{n+1}}\right] \, dx$$

```
int /. n -> 3
```

output not as I wanted:
$$\int_0^1 \text{Evaluate}\left[\frac{x^3}{(x+1)^{3+1}}\right] \, dx$$

I wanted:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{(x+1)^{4}} \, dx$$

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly what [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) was designed for:

```
int = Inactivate[Integrate[x^n/(x + 1)^(n + 1), {x, 0, 1}], Integrate]
```

[image]

```
int /. n -> 3
```

[image]

(Notice also the light shading of the integral sign and the d to indicate the inactivation)

Answer (score 3):

I found a way, but does the code really have to be so ridiculous for such a simple task?

```
int = HoldForm[Integrate[x^n/(x + 1)^(n + 1), {x, 0, 1}]]
HoldForm[a] /. 
  HoldPattern[
    a] -> (int /. n -> 3 /. Integrate -> Evaluate /. 
     HoldForm -> integr) /. integr -> Integrate
```

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{(x+1)^{n+1}} \, dx$$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{(x+1)^4} \, dx$$

Answer (score 3):

You can use Trott-Strzebonski or `RuleCondition` or controlled evaluation; see [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29317/replacement-inside-held-expression), which might be considered a duplicate.

Variations:

```
int = HoldForm[Integrate[x^n/(x + 1)^(n + 1), {x, 0, 1}]];

int /. e_Times :> Block[{n = 3}, e /; True]
int /. e_Times :> Block[{n = 3}, RuleCondition[e, True]]

(*  HoldForm[Integrate[x^3/(1 + x)^4, {x, 0, 1}]]  *)
```

But not:

```
int /. e_Times :> Block[{n = 3}, e]

(*
HoldForm[Integrate[
   Block[{n = 3}, x^n/(x + 1)^(n + 1)], 
   {x, 0, 1}]]
*)
```

These also give the desired result:

```
int /. e_Times :>
  With[{i = e /. n -> 3}, RuleCondition[i, True]]
int /. e : Times[n, __] | Plus[n, __] | Power[_, n] :> 
  With[{i = e /. n -> 3}, RuleCondition[i, True]]
int /. HoldForm[Integrate[i_, rest___]] :> 
  With[{e = i /. n -> 3}, HoldForm[Integrate[e, rest]]]
int /. HoldForm[f_[args___]] :>
  Block[{n = 3}, HoldForm[f[##]] &[args]]
int /. HoldForm[f_[args___]] :>
  (HoldForm[f[##]] & @@ ({args} /. n -> 3))


(*  HoldForm[Integrate[x^3/(1 + x)^4, {x, 0, 1}]]  *)
```

Note that the very first variation assumes all the instances of `n` occur inside a `Times`, which is true in the OP's example.  The pattern `e : Times[n, __] | Plus[n, __] | Power[_, n]` comprises other forms, but not all possible forms (e.g. not `Sin[n] x`).
The last three variations are more general. The third to last allows the integrand to be evaluated; the last two allow all arguments to be evaluated, should `n` appear in the limits of integration, say.

There is a difference between `ReplaceAll` (`... /. n -> 3`) and `Block[{n = 3},...]` if `n` appears in another function that holds its arguments, which does not occur in the OP's example.  This applies to any of the variations above.  In `ReplaceAll`, the symbol `n` will be replaced by `3` but not evaluated inside a function that holds its arguments. In `Block`, since `n` is not evaluated inside such a function, it won't be replaced by `3`.