# Another difference between Set and SetDelayed. Evaluation shortcut?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, variable-definitions

A little while ago I wondered why

```
f[x_] = f[x]
```

gives an infinite iteration. I ended up discovering the following difference in evaluation between `Set` and `SetDelayed` with `Evaluate`.

```
count = 0;
ClearAll @ a
a /; (count++ < 20) = {a}
a // OwnValues
count = 0;
a
```

Output

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{a}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
{HoldPattern[a /; count++ < 20] :> {a}}
{a}
```

and

```
count = 0;
ClearAll@b
b /; (count++ < 20) := Evaluate@{b}
b // OwnValues
count = 0;
b
```

Output

```
{HoldPattern[b /; count++ < 20] :> {b}}
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{b}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Can somebody explain the difference? Can we say that there is an evaluation shortcut at work here?

**Related**

This is a follow up question: [Strange results of definitions using OwnValues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40186/4330)

[Why x = x doesn't cause an infinite loop, but f[x_] := f[x] does?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39957)

[Does Set vs. SetDelayed have any effect after the definition was done?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6346/)

Comment: A nice tool I made says SetDelayed is not called in a usual way in the last example

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Thanks @Rojo

Comment: It's another cache `Update[]` related mystery

Comment: @Rojo I noticed the same thing myself.

Comment: As to the second, there are several symbols that have special ways of being set. Perhaps through `UpValues` (or perhaps you like upcode better :P). Clearly the XValues are some of those. Perhaps, when they overloaded the `SetDelayed` versions, they forgot to return `Null`?

Comment: @Rojo Now we are talking ;). I was also thinking that the evaluation of the examples where I set `OwnValues`  involved up code for `OwnValues`. I am writing a new question about this right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought to give a bit more insight into why `Update` is needed, as pointed out in the other answers. [Its documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update.html) says `Update` may be needed when a change in 1 symbol changes another via a condition test.

In Jacob's example, setting `count = 0` changes the condition test outcome, and thus `a` or `b` on the LHS. Consequently, `a` or `b` on the RHS is supposed to change. However, RHS `a` equals the old LHS `a`, which was undefined because `count>=20`, and needs `Update` to be changed. RHS `b` behaves the same, but was not evaluated in `SetDelayed` because `Evaluate` occurs before `SetDelayed`, so `count` is unchanged, and RHS `b` evaluates to LHS `b` with `count<20`. If we now reset `count=0`, evaluating `b` will return `{b}`.

To illustrate, I modify the example to separate LHS and RHS. MMA is clever enough to automatically update LHS declared as a variable, so I have to make a function:

```
count=0;
ClearAll[LHS,RHS];
LHS[]/;(count++<20)={RHS};
RHS=Unevaluated@LHS[];

count=0;
RHS (* Equals LHS[] with count >= 20 *)

(* Tell Wolfram Language about changes affecting RHS which depends on LHS *)
Update@Unevaluated@LHS;
RHS
```

> LHS[]
>
> {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{LHS[]}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems to make sense and seems to have the right ingredients, but I will have to look at the details to fully understand and to be able to accept.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for the interesting question. I'm learning stuff I never thought about before. I'm looking at the link on infinite evaluation and trying to piece out the intricacies..

Answer (score 3):

*Extended comment. Also: If Rojo wants to post an answer, I can delete this*

It seems Rojo was right, guessing that it had to do with `Update`.

```
count = 0;
ClearAll@a2
a2 /; (Update[Unevaluated@a2]; count++ < 20) = {a2}
a2 // OwnValues
count = 0;
a2
```

Output

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{a2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
{HoldPattern[a2 /; (Update[Unevaluated[a2]]; count++ < 20)] :> {a2}}
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{a2}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

I think user obsolesced rightly pointed out why there is an additional pair of brackets in the first output. This is because there is already a pair of brackets on the right hand side of `Set` and `{a2}` is evaluated rather than `a2`.

Comment: The number of braces is different because `{a2}` is output instead of `a2`.

Answer (score 2):

Also an extended comment; using `Update[]` makes the first recursion behave as expected:

```
count = 0;
ClearAll@a
a /; (count++ < 20) = {a};
count = 0;
Update[]
a
```

> ```
> {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{a}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
> ```

Apparently the LHS condition is affected by the use of `Set` versus `SetDelayed`.  Certainly worth more exploration, but for me that will have to wait.