# Strange results of definitions using OwnValues

Tags: evaluation

I am asking this question simultatenously with [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40182/4330), which is strongly related.

I was trying to see if I could create the behaviour as in that question without using `Condition` by setting `OwnValues`. I ran into the following strange behaviour.

The following gives an infinite recursion

```
Clear[c]
OwnValues[c] = {HoldPattern[c] -> {c}}
```

So does this

```
Clear[d]
OwnValues[d] := {HoldPattern[d] -> {d}}
```

But this does not

```
Clear[e]
OwnValues[e] := {HoldPattern[e] -> Unevaluated@{e}}
```

Actually this last piece evaluates to something other than `Null`, which is not what we expect from `SetDelayed`. Simpler expressions of similar form will also return something. This is what the aside here is about.

Question: Can somebody explain what is going on here? Why do these definitions cause infinite recursions?

### Aside

*Maybe I will write a separate question about this ;)*

**Tool**

I have made the following tool that can show us when a particular function is being called, and with what arguments. It uses `Print` to display this information. Note that it is quite buggy. For now let's only use it on `SetDelayed`. Making both `SetDelayed` and `Set` print this way crashes the kernel I think. This is the tool.

```
SetAttributes[letPrint, HoldAll];
letPrint[symb_] :=
 (
  ClearAttributes[symb, Protected];
  DownValues[symb] = {};
  With[
   {uq = Unique[]},
   uq = False;
   expr : symb[___] /; (uq = ! uq) := (Print[
      Column[{uq, ToString[Unevaluated[symb]], 
        HoldForm@InputForm[expr]}]]; expr)
   ]
  )
```

Now we can do

```
(*warning, overloads and Unprotects SetDelayed*)
letPrint@SetDelayed
```

We then have that

```
Clear[aaa, bbb]
aaa := bbb
```

Prints

```
True (*not really meaningful*)
SetDelayed
aaa:=bbb
```

but

```
Clear[a]
OwnValues[a] = {HoldPattern[a] :> 1};
```

does not print anything. My suspicion is that there is some internal code associated with `OwnValues` that prevents the expression with head `SetDelayed` from being evaluated like normal.

To restore `SetDelayed`, I think you can do

```
Clear@SetDelayed; Protect@SetDelayed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it is related to your other question.

It seems that `SetDelayed` applied to the XValues functions behaves like `Set` in the sense that it returns the stuff it has assigned instead of returning `Null`.

`OwnValues[c] = {HoldPattern[c] -> {c}}` will give an infinite recursion because it will want to return something that requires the evaluation of `c`, after it was assigned to `{c}`.

The second example is the same, due to the above mentioned peculiarity.

`OwnValues[e] := {HoldPattern[e] -> Unevaluated@{e}}` will not because it returs something that doesn't require the evaluation of `e`. And even if it did, that last assignment would replace `e` with `Unevaluated@{e}` which won't iterate again

Comment: But why evaluation of `OwnValues[e] := {HoldPattern[e] -> Unevaluated@{e}}` returns something other than `Null`? "Usual" delayed definitions do not return anything.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. The behaviour of SetX for the XValues is different in more than one way, it is overloaded. For example, it checks that you are assigning valid rules. Perhaps they just forgot to return `Null` when they overloaded it, or perhaps there's a reason :P. It is clearly inconsistent, but it seems to be that way