# How is LHS = RHS; ... ; LHS (nontrivially) different from ... ; RHS

Tags: programming, evaluation, assignment

I'm trying to understand how Mathematica thinks about the results of `Set`.  Suppose we perform `LHS = RHS`.  I'm focusing on when Mathematica considers `LHS` to be fully evaluated and when it decides to evaluate `LHS` again later.

#### Discussion and Examples

Suppose I do the following:

```
(* First example *)
ClearAll[ LHS, f, F ];
LHS = f[x];  (* f[x] *)
f[x_] := F[x]
LHS
(* F[x] *)
```

This is what I would have expected to happen -- `LHS` is re-evaluated at the end.

Now, the following works a bit differently:

```
(* Second example *)
ClearAll[LHS, f, F, changeQ];

changeQ[x_] := False
f[x_?changeQ] := F[x]

LHS = f[x];
changeQ[x] := True
LHS
(* f[x] *)
```

Apparently Mathematica decided not to re-evaluate `LHS` at the end, otherwise it would evaluate to `F[x]`.  This is a case where `LHS` and `f[x]` evaluate to different quantities.

Interestingly enough, swapping the order of two lines in the above changes the outcome:

```
(* Third example *)
ClearAll[LHS, f, F, changeQ];

changeQ[x_] := False
LHS = f[x];

f[x_?changeQ] := F[x]
changeQ[x] := True
LHS
(* F[x] *)
```

Swapping the order made `LHS` re-evaluate at the end, just like in the first example.

This leads me to more formally pose and tentatively answer the question:

#### Question

Suppose, for some choice of `initialCode` and `additionalCode`, we perform

```
initialCode
LHS = f[x];  (* f[x] *)
additionalCode
LHS
```

Assuming that `LHS` originally evaluated to `f[x]`,

1. For what types of `additionalCode` (and possibly `initialCode`) does the final evaluation of `LHS` yield something different from evaluating `f[x]`?
2. If `LHS` and `f[x]` evaluate to different values (as is the case at the end of the second example above), is it possible to somehow "force" `LHS` to evaluate in the same way as `f[x]`?

#### Tentative Answer to Question 1

(Based on evidence from above examples)

- `LHS` will re-evaluate when `additionalCode` gives a down value to `f` (See 1st and 3rd examples above)
- `LHS` will not re-evaluate in general.  (See 2nd example above, where a down value was given to a different function, `changedQ`.)

#### Follow Up

Assuming the tentative answer is along the right track, I'm looking for two things:

- How does Mathematica 'know' when to re-evaluate `LHS`?  I'm particularly interested in the vocabulary used to describe the process.
- Are there any other conditions under which `LHS` re-evaluates?
- Is there a generic way to force `LHS` to re-evaluate?  (This is similar to the second question above.)

Of course, I'd welcome any suggestions for good references on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Behavior you're describing is briefly mentioned in
[last paragraph of "Controlling Infinite Evaluation" tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ControllingInfiniteEvaluation.html#13261)
and very similar example is shown in documentation of [Update](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update.html) function.

It's related to how *Mathematica* optimizes evaluation, how it decides that expression has not changed since last evaluation and whether it needs to be re-evaluated.

> For what types of `additionalCode` (and possibly `initialCode`) does the final evaluation of `LHS` yield something different from evaluating `f[x]`?

If evaluation of `f[x]`, before evaluating `additionalCode`, depends on `Condition` or `PatternTest` and evaluation of `additionalCode` changes some symbols in such a way that results of said `Condition` or `PatternTest` changes. Then evaluation of `LHS` will give different result than evaluation of `f[x]` after `additionalCode` was evaluated.

I don't know details of internal optimizations and above answer is based on what I recall from my experience, it's **not** backed up by any definite reference nor by conclusive experiments with *Mathematica*.

> If `LHS` and `f[x]` evaluate to different values (as is the case at the end of the second example above), is it possible to somehow "force" `LHS` to evaluate in the same way as `f[x]`?

Yes, evalute `Update[f]` after evaluation of `additionalCode`:

```
(* Second example *)
ClearAll[LHS, f, F, changeQ];

changeQ[x_] := False
f[x_?changeQ] := F[x]

LHS = f[x];
changeQ[x] := True

Update[f]

LHS
(* F[x] *)
```

> How does Mathematica 'know' when to re-evaluate `LHS`? I'm particularly interested in the vocabulary used to describe the process.
>
> Are there any other conditions under which `LHS` re-evaluates?

Daniel Lichtblau shed some light on this in [answer to "Mathematica execution-time bug: symbol names" post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5408385).

> Is there a generic way to force LHS to re-evaluate? (This is similar to the second question above.)

Yes, use [Update](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Update.html) function.
If you know which symbols where affected, pass them to `Update`, otherwise call `Update[]` without arguments.

## Related posts

- [Why x = x doesn't cause an infinite loop, but f[x_] := f[x] does?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39957/14303)
- [Another difference between Set and Setdelayed. Evaluation shortcut?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40182/14303)

Comment: You said all I was going to and more. +1!