# Alternatives and the Flat attribute

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language, attributes

When a head has the attribute `Flat` then the pattern matcher is able to pick out a sublist of its arguments, even though the structure doesn't match:

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
f[a, b, c, d] /. f[a, b] -> Sequence[]
(* f[c, d] *)
f[a, b, c, d] /. f[c, d] -> Sequence[]
(* f[a, b] *)
```

This makes sense because the `Flat` attribute asserts that `f[a, b, c, d]` is among other things equivalent to `f[f[a, b], c, d]`.

However, as soon as I put the shorter sublist inside `Alternatives`, the pattern matcher no longer seems to look for this restructuring:

```
f[a, b, c, d] /. f[a, b] | f[c, d] -> Sequence[]
(* f[a, b, c, d] *)
```

It doesn't matter here that the `f[c, d]` is trying to do the same thing. If I use `f[a, b] | {}` it doesn't match anything either.

I have tested this with Mathematica 11.0.0.

The docs of `Alternatives` don't seem to give away a reason why this would be the case. I found [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105472/2305) but I can no longer reproduce the behaviour described there in 11.0.0.

Is this a bug or the intended behaviour? And either way, is there a better workaround than `{f[a, b] -> Sequence[], f[c, d] -> Sequence[]}`?

Comment: Is it because `ReplaceAll` tries to match some subsequence of the expression and `f[a,f[b,c]|{},d]` doesn't match `f[a,b,c,d]` because it wouldn't evaluate to it?

Comment: @swish I'm not sure. [Rolf Mertig found out](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34999456#34999456) that it does work if you give `Alternatives` itself the `Flat` attribute, in which case your example still wouldn't evaluate to `f[a,b,c,d]`.

Comment: As a workaround could you use `f[f[a, b] | f[c, d]]` as the pattern?

Comment: @SimonWoods That doesn't work for me (I'm currently on 10.4 though, will have to test 11.0 tomorrow).

Comment: @SimonWoods It sort of works in 11.0 but only removes one match. (Which can of course be fixed by using `//.`.)

Comment: Also, my actual use case uses `Times` where that doesn't seem to work either, probably because the outer `Times` vanishes immediately.

Comment: Re: Simon's workaround I think one would only expect it to remove one match?  I mean even if `Alternatives` is corrected/extended for your example it will still need `//.`?