# How could I define function with function such as Coefficient?

Tags: function-construction, syntax

For example, I have

```
eq1=ax+by+cz;
```

and then I want to define new function, $eq2$, as

```
eq2[x_]:=Coefficient[eq1,a];
```

eq2 supposed to be function of x and in this case

```
eq2[x]=x;
```

However, eq2 is "actually" equal x. I mean it doesn't matter which x I put to the argument of eq2, I always get "x". For example, eq2[1]=x, eq2[2]=x.

How could I define the eq2 and make it really a function of x?

Thanks.

Comment: `eq2[x_] := Evaluate@Coefficient[eq1, a]`

Comment: @corey979 I have tried  your suggestion and it's work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have read that question after you mentioned it. However, I don't think it's duplicate. In my case, I already used SetDelayed, so the result seem to depends on x but it's not. Do you have any comments about my problem if it is duplicate?

Comment: Does `eq2[x_] = Coefficient[eq1,a];` work?  (I.e., use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`. `Set` is more or less equivalent to corey's use of `SetDelayed` and `Evaluate`.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes it works. Do you have explanation? I have tried to find the explanation from the question you mentioned but I "think" I can't find because if I use     Set, it seem to be set eq2 at that value and not depends on changing of x in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a question of [What is the difference between Set and SetDelayed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed)  The issue is also discussed in the tutorial [Immediate and Delayed Definitions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html); more can be found in [Leonid's book](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node97.html).  A subtle difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed` is discussed in [Does Set vs. SetDelayed have any effect after the definition was done?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6346/does-set-vs-setdelayed-have-any-effect-after-the-definition-was-done)

Let's think of the OP's code and its alternative

```
eq2[x_] := Coefficient[eq1,a];
eq2[x_] = Coefficient[eq1,a];
```

in more general terms as the alternatives

```
f[x_] := expression;
f[x_] = expression;
```

The first, `SetDelayed` definition creates a rule so that the code `f[x0]` results in the literal occurrences of `x` in `expression` to be replaced by `x0` and then the resulting expression is evaluated.  In the OP's case, the expression is `Coefficient[eq1,a]`, which literally contains no `x`.  By "literal," I mean that the symbol `x` has to occur in the unevaluated code. The symbol `eq1` is literally just a symbol.  Only after it is evaluated, does one obtain the expression `a x + b y + c z` that contains `x`.  That brings us to the difference with `Set`.

The second, `Set` definition creates a rule so that the code `f[x0]` results in the literal occurrences of `x` in the evaluated `expression` to be replaced by `x0`. Note I said that `expression` is evaluated ***before*** the rule is created. In the OP's case, the expression `Coefficient[eq1,a]` is evaluated, resulting in `x`, which results in a rule that would replace `eq2[x0]` by `x0`.

The actual rules created may be inspected with [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) (or [`? eq2`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Information.html)):

```
eq1 = a x + b y + c z;   (* note the spaces between a x, etc. *)

eq2[x_] := Coefficient[eq1, a];
DownValues[eq2]
(*  {HoldPattern[eq2[x_]] :> Coefficient[eq1, a]}  *)

eq2[x_] = Coefficient[eq1, a];
DownValues[eq2]
(*  {HoldPattern[eq2[x_]] :> x}  *)
```

In the first case, `eq2[x0]` would be replaced by `Coefficient[eq1, a]`.

In the second case, `eq2[x0]` would be replaced by `x0` (since the `x` in the pattern `x_` matches `x0`).

As noted in [a comment to an answer of the linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setdelayed#comment25412_8831), it's a good idea to use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) if there are symbols that should not be evaluated when using `Set`.  In the OP's case, it seems `x` is to be treated as a symbol.  If it had a numeric value at the time `eq2[x_] =...` is executed, then the definition of `eq2[x]` would not depend on the argument `x`.

```
x = 3;

(* incorrect *)
eq2[x_] = Coefficient[eq1, a];
DownValues[eq2]
(*  {HoldPattern[eq2[x_]] :> 3}  *)

eq2[5]
(*  3  *)

(* correct *)
Block[{x},
  eq2[x_] = Coefficient[eq1, a];
  ];
DownValues[eq2]
(*  {HoldPattern[eq2[x_]] :> x}  *)

eq2[5]
(*  5  *)
```