# Why changing list's head takes time?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider

```
AbsoluteTiming[Range[10^7];][[1]]
```

> 0.035000

and

```
AbsoluteTiming[HoldComplete @@ Range[10^7];][[1]]
```

> 0.725000

Why it takes twenty times longer to change head than to create a list? Since `HoldComplete` doesn't evaluate arguments one would think that head changing should be fast.

Comment: Because `HoldComplete` unpacks, when `Apply` is used (or, rather, `Apply` unpacks).

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin no preamble, but clearly answer material.

Comment: @YvesKlett All right, I followed your suggestion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your example, you originally create a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array/). If you read about packed arrays in the answers in the linked question, in [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/6.1.html) or elsewhere, you will see that these are special objects, lower-level than general Mathematica lists / expressions.

Because of this, not all Mathematica operations preserve these objects. Those which don't are said to *unpack*. Some considerations regarding (avoiding) unpacking can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/are-there-guidelines-for-avoiding-the-unpacking-of-a-packed-array). In particular, it was mentioned and illustrated there that `Apply` necessarily unpacks. This is just because of its nature: it replaces the current head of an expression with a different head.

It is easy to check whether or not unpacking happens - use `On["Packing"]`:

```
On["Packing"]

HoldComplete @@ Range[10]
```

> During evaluation of In[125]:= Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack1: Unpacking array with dimensions {10}. >>

```
(*  HoldComplete[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  *)

Off["Packing"]
```

Unpacking is a process of replacing a packed array with its unpacked, higher-level equivalent generic Mathematica list. For large arrays, this can take quite some time, which is what you observed. This has nothing to do with `HoldComplete`, because unpacking happens slightly earlier, and has nothing to do directly with the top-level evaluation - which is the only evaluation that `HoldComplete` may affect. Unpacking is a lower-level action.

Comment: Setting the 0th `Part` to something other than `List` also unpacks. So, although it's true that `Apply` does unpack, I think the reason is that packed arrays can only have head `List`, rather than that this is due to `Apply` itself.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Sure, I implied this. Perhaps, I could have articulated this point better, thanks.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - I remember reading in the docs that Range[] had some sort of special internal representation, but don't recall it was ever explained beyond that. Makes me wonder about how best to use this function (so as to avoid the problem OP stumbled into). Interesting.

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 It's not just about `Range` - all packed arrays are like that. You can think of them as an internal (lower-level) data type on which all relevant Mathematica's built-in functions have been overloaded. Some of the suggestions how to use them effectively you can find in the links I gave in the answer.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - I've read lots of stuff you and others have written on the interaction between packed and regular objects, and potential for unexpected performance losses caused by unpacking. I guess what I was trying to convey was mild surprise that Range[] itself is represented as a packed array. Again, the docs mention range being 'special' but I've never come across any other details. Another reason this surprised me a bit is that Range[1,800], when evaluated alone, doesn't return as PackedArray[Integer, <800>]. I didn't think packed arrays automatically unpacked like that (in isolation).

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 It seems rather natural that `Range` produces a packed array, since it will clearly be an array of integers. In principle, one could create `Range` that would have too large integers, but in practice that would require too much memory to hold it. Re: unpacking - don't quite follow you: ``Range[1, 800] // Developer`PackedArrayQ`` returns `True`, so it is packed all right.

Comment: I guess I was expecting that a packed object would remain packed unless explicitly unpacked OR unpacked internally to perform a mixed calculation. Therefore, I was expecting a MMA 'object-type' representation in the front end, rather than the explicit list that gets printed as output (an unpacked representation).

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 Yes, you can't judge by the visual representation for packed arrays. They look just like unpacked ones.

Comment: I appreciate the edit, but to "crate a packed array" sounded quite appropriate. :)