# Ways to access lists inside lists

Tags: list-manipulation, documentation

I have gone through some [reference material](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice) but I am not getting really good links that will help me grow understanding of `pure functions,patterns and list manipulations combined together`. Most of the examples referred in documentation are for single list(without sublists).

For example, say from a list I wanted to pick first element of every sublist, say,`fi = FactorInteger[12]`so I used

```
Table[fi[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[fi]}]
```

I try to do everything with `Table`.
Though it should be achievable via other simple ways too. Can someone please put some examples where one can get to learn how to access data from lists of sublists and how to decompose it. This might sound pretty trivial to lot of people but I couldn't find books and links either that can give insight into combining these Mathematica features together.

Comment: Did you have a look at [guide/ListManipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html)? For the given example `fi[[All, 1]]`, `First /@ fi` and `#[[1]] & /@ fi` would work.

Comment: yes I have seen

Comment: For what it's worth, in your particular example, the `Table` expression can be replaced with `# & @@@ fi`. Is that the sort of thing you're interested in?

Comment: yes..these kind of examples to practice with

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but everything you're asking for is easily found in the built-in documentation. I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to answer this as I think it is helpful to gather multiple methods in one place, and such a list is not, as far as I know, easily found in the documentation.

```
a = FactorInteger[269325];  (* sample data *)

a[[All, 1]]
First[a\[Transpose]]
a.{1, 0}
First /@ a
# & @@@ a
#[[1]] & /@ a
```

All lines output: `{3, 5, 7, 19}`.

`a[[All, 1]]` is I believe the fastest general method, and should usually be your first choice.

`First[a\[Transpose]]` (this looks better in a Notebook) is a fast method for rectangular data.

`a.{1, 0}` shows a numeric method using `Dot` that is applicable to arrays of known dimensions, such as the output of `FactorInteger`.

`First /@ a` is probably the most explicit and easiest to read.

`# & @@@ a` illustrates the use of pure functions and `Apply` at level one.

Be aware that the latter methods are often slower because [they will unpack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5258/121).

Here are timings for these methods on packed data:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing @ Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

a = RandomInteger[1*^9, {500000, 2}];

a[[All, 1]]          // timeAvg
First[a\[Transpose]] // timeAvg
a.{1, 0}             // timeAvg
First /@ a           // timeAvg
# & @@@ a            // timeAvg
#[[1]] & /@ a        // timeAvg
```

> 0.00512
>
> 0.0012976
>
> 0.011984
>
> 0.04304
>
> 0.2122
>
> 0.04492

And unpackable data:

```
a = RandomChoice[{Pi, "x", 1}, {500000, 2}];

a[[All, 1]]          // timeAvg
First[a\[Transpose]] // timeAvg
a.{1, 0}             // timeAvg
First /@ a           // timeAvg
# & @@@ a            // timeAvg
#[[1]] & /@ a        // timeAvg
```

> 0.01684
>
> 0.02308
>
> 0.2122
>
> 0.078
>
> 0.0968
>
> 0.1592

Comment: If you're listing them all, how about `Part[a, All, 1]`

Comment: @bills That's just the long form of `a[[All, 1]]`, and I didn't include the long form of any of these.  Do you think these should be included?

Comment: Wizard - I kind of like the idea of "all the ways to do it", but it's your call...

Comment: Here's one you dont have: `First@Transpose[a]` or even more obscurely `First@Thread[a]`

Comment: @bills `Transpose` is excellent for rectangular data and I should have remember to include it!

Comment: Is the sole difference between packable and unpackable arrays the commonality of the data type in the array?  The linked question didn't help me as much as it probably should have.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:thanks for taking time to write it and understanding my concern.Your posts are always places to learn from.

Comment: @Blackbird You're welcome, and thanks, I try.

Comment: @bobthechemist Packed arrays must be rectangular (or vector) data of machine-size numbers of type Real, Integer, or Complex.  Arrays are not packed automatically, but may be packed by functions that auto-compile, or manually using ``Developer`ToPackedArray``.