# Averaging multiple 2D data sets

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have multiple data sets, each of which is a 2D matrix. I want to construct a new 2D Matrix in which each element is the average of that element for all the original data sets. i.e

```
NewMatrix[i][j] =1/N *(Matrix1[i][j] + Matrix2[i][j] + ... + MatrixN[i][j])
```

I can't quite figure out how to do it in *Mathematica*.

Thanks

Comment: You might find some of the tutorials (espcially those on linear algebra) useful: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MatricesAndLinearAlgebra.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a pretty basic question but since you're new here let me get you started.  Many functions in *Mathematica* are natively designed to work on vectors, arrays, and tensors.  That means that such an operation is or at least may be directly analogous to the non-array form.  Suppose you have:

```
a1 = RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}];
a2 = RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}];
a3 = RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}];
```

You then need merely:

```
(a1 + a2 + a3) / 3
```

Or:

```
Mean[{a1, a2, a3}]
```

Just as you would if `a1`, `a2` and `a3` were individual numbers.  This will be much faster than a manual procedural operation, unless you are going to compile that procedural code.

---

**A sidebar**

You could define all three arrays at once using:

```
{a1, a2, a3} = RandomInteger[9, {3, 5, 5}];
```

There is a subtle yet important difference however.  This more concise form will unpack the packed integer array that is produced by `RandomInteger`, resulting in slower numeric operations on those expressions.

Comment: Subtle indeed!.  You've [already told us](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28435/7167) that arrays are not packed automatically and I've [since learned](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3497/7167) that `On["Packing"]` tells us when a command is unpacking an array, but is there any resource that should clue us in that `RandomInteger` (or any other function) will be returning a packed array?

Comment: @bobthechemist -- I know he has the name "Mr.Wizard", but how does he know that stuff?

Comment: Ah, thanks very much. I'm more accustomed to coding environments like java where you have to deal with each element individually, I didn't realise Mathematica dealt with matrices in such an elegant way.

Comment: @bob You can check if an array is packed with ``Developer`PackedArrayQ``.  I'm not sure if it is expressly stated that `RandomInteger`, `Range`, etc. return packed arrays, but it would be disappointing if they did not.  Be aware that unpacked arrays may be automatically packed on-the-fly by functions which auto-compile (at some threshold) such as `Map` and `Fold`, e.g. `Map[N, list]` on a `list` of more than 100 unpacked integers will return a packed list of reals.  Also see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5258/121) for avoiding or understanding unpacking.

Comment: @Jagra Thanks for making me smile. :^)  What I know has been learned from roughly equal parts of experimentation, reading MathGroup and other resources at http://library.wolfram.com, and participation on this site (and StackOverflow before it).

Comment: @bob Since I feel this is an unexpected behavior I opened [a new question on the topic.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28998/121)