# Assigning row of values to a lower triangular matrix

Tags: matrix

I want to assign a linear row of values to the elements of a lower triangular matrix,

i.e., if the row of values is `{1,2,3,4}`, then the matrix (4 X 4) should be:

```
{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 2, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}
```

***I can do this with a (nested) For loop, but was wondering if there was any easier way.***

Thank you for your help and time in advance

Comment: How about an arbitrary set of values, say {1.12, 2.45, 3.77, 4.23}. How would I transfer these to a lowertriangular matrix?  Mr. Wizard's answer looks pertinent but any other way? Thanks

Comment: Jorge, you shouldn't be so fast to Accept an answer.  This question is still young. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I agree :P Also +1 for waking this site up :P

Comment: First battery of timings added to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vals = {1,2,3,4};
n = Length@vals

NestList[PadLeft[#, n+1][[ ;; -2]] &, vals, n-1] // Transpose
```

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 2, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}
> ```

30% faster approach:

```
NestList[ArrayPad[#, {-1, 1}] &, Reverse@vals, n - 1] // Reverse
```

Comment: It appears we were thinking alike. +1  I'll be interested to see how this one performs.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Comparison could be interesting :) I like @sebhofer \`s array because I was approaching to this with `MapIndexed`, it wasn't pretty.

Comment: Oh, I think the `MapIndexed` solution is kind of cute :)

Comment: See my timings; I found one faster but it was inspired by your method.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not as fast as yours but faster :) `Array` seems to be panacea lately :)

Comment: I added one with `Partition` I quite like, though it's a bit slower.

Comment: I also added a note regarding the mass application of `PadRight` that I think will interest you.

Comment: panda-34 smoked us both with a function I've never used before, and perhaps haven't even seen before.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So do I. That's the lesson to dig deeper in documentation next time :)

Answer (score 11):

```
vals = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Reverse /@ 
 ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, Length@vals], vals, 1, 0, Times, List]
```

And a couple of special forces functions:

```
Reverse@HankelMatrix@Reverse@vals
LowerTriangularize@ToeplitzMatrix@vals
```

---

(added by J. M.)

The problem with `LowerTriangularize @ ToeplitzMatrix @ vals`, altho it is compact, is that one is stuffing a matrix with values that are then set to zero later, which is a waste of effort. It is better to construct the lower triangular Toeplitz matrix outright with specially chosen vectors, like so:

```
ToeplitzMatrix[#, SparseArray[1 -> First[#], Length[#]]] & @ vals
```

Comment: Wow!  I've never used those (esoteric?) matrix functions before.  +1!

Answer (score 8):

I propose these:

```
vals = {1, 2, 3, 4};

n = 4;

SparseArray[Array[Band[{#, 1}] -> vals[[#]] &, n], n] // Normal

Reverse @ PadRight @ NestList[Rest, Reverse @ vals, n-1]

PadLeft @ NestList[Most, vals, n-1] ~Reverse~ {1, 2}

UpperTriangularize[NestList[RotateRight, vals, n-1]] ~Reverse~ {1, 2}

With[{r = Reverse@vals}, PadLeft[r, n, 0, n - #] & ~Array~ n]

#@Partition[#@vals, n, 1, 1, 0] &[Reverse]

PadRight[#, n] & /@ NestList[Rest, Reverse @ vals, n - 1] // Reverse

Table[
  v = Prepend[Most@v, vals[[i]]],
  {v, {ConstantArray[0, n]}},
  {i, n}
] // First
```

All produce:

> ```
> {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0}, {3, 2, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}
> ```

#### Notes:

Something I've [known for a while](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5259/121) but didn't account for here is that `PadLeft`/`PadRight` on a ragged array of packed lists unpacks.  My second and third methods have this problem.  By using `PadRight` on each packed vector these can be greatly improved for that specific case.

---

## Timings

Alright, I believe we have enough options for the first timing comparison.  Using my flavor of Timo's `timeAvg`:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]

timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
```

And this (packed) data:

```
n = 1500;
vals = RandomInteger[9999, 1500];
```

The timings for my proposals:

```
SparseArray[Array[Band[{#, 1}] -> vals[[#]] &, n], n]                   // timeAvg
Reverse@PadRight@NestList[Rest, Reverse @ vals, n - 1]                  // timeAvg
PadLeft@NestList[Most, vals, n - 1] ~Reverse~ {1, 2}                    // timeAvg
UpperTriangularize[NestList[RotateRight, vals, n - 1]] ~Reverse~ {1, 2} // timeAvg
With[{r = Reverse@vals}, PadLeft[r, n, 0, n - #] & ~Array~ n]           // timeAvg
#@Partition[#@vals, n, 1, 1, 0] &[Reverse]                              // timeAvg
PadRight[#, n] & /@ NestList[Rest, Reverse @ vals, n - 1] // Reverse    // timeAvg
Table[
  v = Prepend[Most@v, vals[[i]]],
  {v, {ConstantArray[0, n]}},
  {i, n}
] // First // timeAvg
```

> 1.669
>
> 0.1342
>
> 0.1778
>
> 0.0362
>
> 0.003744
>
> 0.008112
>
> 0.004992
>
> 0.003992

And other's proposals:

```
f[i_, j_] /; i < j := 0
f[i_, j_] := vals[[i - j + 1]]
Array[f, {n, n}] // timeAvg

Table[If[i >= j, vals[[i - j + 1]], 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] // timeAvg

NestList[PadLeft[#, n + 1][[ ;; -2]] &, vals, n - 1] // Transpose // timeAvg

NestList[ArrayPad[#, {-1, 1}] &, Reverse@vals, n - 1] // Reverse // timeAvg

Reverse /@ ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, Length@vals], vals, 1, 0, Times, List] // timeAvg

LowerTriangularize@MapIndexed[RotateRight, ConstantArray[Reverse@vals, n]] // timeAvg

Array[vals[[#1 - #2 + 1]] UnitStep[#1 - #2] &, {n, n}] // timeAvg
```

> 1.981
>
> 1.576
>
> 0.010608
>
> 0.006864
>
> 0.2246
>
> 0.134
>
> 3.573

I expected `Band` to perform better which is why I led with it, but it actually scales very poorly.  Kuba's method is faster than any of my four original ones but it inspired my fifth method which is the fastest so far on this test.  I'll update timings as more options come in and with more detailed tests.

---

panda-34 get's his own special section for these beautiful incantations; the fastest yet!

```
Reverse @ HankelMatrix @ Reverse @ vals      // timeAvg
LowerTriangularize @ ToeplitzMatrix @ vals   // timeAvg
```

> 0.002872
>
> 0.002496

Comment: I like yours the best btw, especially the `NestList` ones

Comment: @sebhofer Thank you.

Comment: Could you test my `MapIndexed` solution? I think it should be reasonably fast...

Comment: @sebhofer Sorry, I missed your adding that.  I'll get working on it.

Comment: Wow... clearly `PadLeft` wins. Nice one!

Comment: See if you can beat `LowerTriangularize@ToeplitzMatrix@vals` (I added it to my answer)

Comment: The need for `LowerTriangularize[]` in the Toeplitz solution is rather wasteful; try `ToeplitzMatrix[#, SparseArray[1 -> First[#], Length[#]]] & @ vals`.

Comment: @J.M. Would you consider adding that to panda-34's answer, unless you wish to post it separately?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend `Array` since it is faster than `Table` and `UnitStep` (faster than `If`)

```
(m = Array[(#1 - #2 + 1) UnitStep[#1 - #2] &, {4, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If there is an input vector e.g.

```
v = {3, 5, 7, 11};
```

we can reformulate existing approach to this form:

```
Array[ v[[#1 - #2 + 1]] UnitStep[#1 - #2] &, {4, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand but I assumed that the OP wanted an arbitrary vector for values.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now that I reread the question I think you are right

Comment: It should be clear enough to beginners that one can play with pure functions inside `Array` to define different vectors.

Comment: So give us an example. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Exempli gratia: `Array[(#1^2 - 2 #2 + 3) UnitStep[#1 - #2] &, {4, 4}]`

Comment: I'm still not seeing an arbitrary list; suppose `values = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}` -- what then?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Then use another approach (see edit).

Comment: See, now that wasn't so hard. ;-) +1

Answer (score 6):

Variation of Nasser's code (which I find a bit cleaner, although it is longer)

```
f[i_, j_] /; i < j := 0
f[i_, j_] := i - j + 1
Array[f, {4, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

For arbitrary values one could adapt this and do

```
vals={1,3,5,7};
f[i_, j_] /; i < j := 0
f[i_, j_] := vals[[i - j + 1]]
```

And another one, just to be silly (and to not let Mr. Wizard win with all his `NestList` based solutions ;)

```
vals={1,3,5,7};
LowerTriangularize@MapIndexed[RotateRight, ConstantArray[Reverse@vals, Length@vals]]
```

Comment: I really like `Array`; you could also write `Array[If[# >= #2, # - #2 + 1, 0] &, {4, 4}]` which is closer to Nasser's.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I thought about adding your suggestion but Artes has it in his answer, so I guess it's not necessary...

Answer (score 5):

one way

```
(m = Table[If[i >= j, i - j + 1, 0], {i, 4}, {j, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**answer comment:**

```
 r = {3, 99, 27, 49};
(m = Table[If[i >=  j, r[[i - j + 1]], 0], {i, 4}, {j, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How about an arbitrary set of values, say {1.12, 2.45, 3.77, 4.23}. How would I transfer these to a lowertriangular matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
ClearAll[toLTM]
toLTM[n_Integer] := Composition[Transpose, PadLeft, Range, Reverse, Range]@n
(* or toLTM[n_Integer] := Reverse /@ PadLeft @ Range @ Range @ n *)

toLTM[v_List] := Transpose @ 
  PadLeft @ Extract[v, List /@ Range @ Reverse @ Range @ Length @ v]

toLTM @ 4 // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
>  4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
toLTM @ CharacterRange["a", "d"] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{a} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{b} & \text{a} & 0 & 0 \\
>  \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} & 0 \\
>  \text{d} & \text{c} & \text{b} & \text{a} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

```
PadRight[Take[RotateRight[Reverse@list, #], #], 4] & /@ Range[Length[list]]
```

or

```
    NestList[RotateRight, Reverse@list, 
   Length@list][[-Length@list ;; -1]] // LowerTriangularize
```