# Cyclic and Non-cyclic Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

Mathematica has a built in function to generate all permutations of a given list of elements; `Permutations`

I can't find an equivalent function to generate cyclic permutations only in the documentation. Here is my function that achieves this goal:

```
CyclicPermutations[list_] := 
 RotateRight[list, #] & /@ (Range[Length[list]] - 1)
```

Is there an in-built function somewhere that I've not been able to find?

And then a similar question which I don't have my own answer to. I would like to also generate all noncyclic permutations, ie. the set of permutations minus the set of cyclic permutations. I'm not sure of a good way to do this, I can think up some methods which use `Permutations` and my `CyclicPermutations` and then maybe `DeleteCases`, but I think this will be comparatively very inefficient. Does anyone else have a better method?

Comment: `Permute[#, CyclicGroup[Length@#]] &`

Comment: For noncyclic permutations: have you seen `Complement[]`?

Comment: @yode Please post an answer.  I did not remember that `Permute` can work with a group.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per the request, I post my comment as an answer:

## First question

```
cy := Permute[#, CyclicGroup[Length@#]] &
cy[Range@5]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}, {3, 4, 5, 1, 2}, {4, 5, 1, 2,3}, {5, 1, 2, 3, 4}}

## Second question

We can use the `Complement` mentioned by J.M. in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120264/cyclic-and-non-cyclic-permutations#comment325701_120264). I suppose that the order is $5$; then, you can use the following method to get noncyclic permutations:

```
Complement[Permutations[Range[5]], cy[Range@5]]
```

> {{1,2,3,5,4},{1,2,4,3,5},{1,2,4,5,3},{1,2,5,3,4},{1,2,5,4,3},{1,3,2,4,5},{1,3,2,5,4},<<101>>,{5,3,4,2,1},{5,4,1,2,3},{5,4,1,3,2},{5,4,2,1,3},{5,4,2,3,1},{5,4,3,1,2},{5,4,3,2,1}}

Comment: Sadly `Permute[#, CyclicGroup[Length@#]] &` proves to be orders of magnitude slower than what the OP started with! :-(

Comment: `Complement` is great, thanks for your help

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The `CyclicPermutations` just do one calculation to get a list.But the `cy` do `n` times...

Comment: `CyclicPermutations[Range@5]` returns `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}}`.  How is `Permute` better here?

Answer (score 9):

```
cp=HankelMatrix[#, RotateRight@#] &;
```

Should perform quite well and returns packed array...

Comment: Great!  I never remember these specialized generators.  This clearly should be the Accepted answer.

Comment: I guess my memory does not extend [three years back](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29431/121) :-/

Comment: I think this is a winning answer. :)

Comment: But note my `cy` can be used by `cy[{2, 7, 9}]`,which make life ease in some case.Of course,it out of this topic.

Comment: @yode `cp[{2, 7, 9}]` works too though, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Er..little mistake by me,thanks for point out. :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - had not seen that, but I've a library of sneaky functions using Hankel/Toeplitz matrices to build "interesting" configurations... glad you like it.

Comment: @ciao If you really do would you consider sharing it?  I like your imagination and knowledge and I am sure I would learn from it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - sure, I'll gather/clean and put as answer to the "elegant array operations" (or whatever it's called) question when I have time. Remind me if I forget.

Comment: @ciao That question is about basic/common transformations and operations.  Would not expression generation be better in its own Q&A?

Answer (score 4):

At least in version 10.1 under Windows there is a performance problem with yode's [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) solution.  For comparison here is his code, Joe's original code, and a variation of my own:

```
fn1[list_] := RotateRight[list, #] & /@ (Range[Length[list]] - 1)

fn2 = Permute[#, CyclicGroup[Length@#]] &;

fn3[a_] := Array[RotateLeft[a, #]&, Length @ a]
```

The results are all equivalent under sorting:

```
Sort @ # @ Range @ 4 & /@ {fn1, fn2, fn3}
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}},
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}},
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}}
> ```

The performance however is not!

```
AbsoluteTiming @ Timing @ Do[#@Range@500, {50}] & /@ {fn1, fn2, fn3} // Column
```

> ```
>  {0.046702, {0.0312002, Null}}
>
>  {2.48765, {2.44922, Null}}
>
>  {0.0456291, {0.0156001, Null}}
> ```

`Permute` on `CyclicGroup` is some fifty times slower than the other methods here.

My `fn3` is just a hair faster than `fn1` and IMHO somewhat cleaner, so it is my proposal.

Comment: I accept the challenge... ;-}

Answer (score 1):

A few more ... The first one using `Partition` not too horribly slow

```
fn4[a_] := Partition[a, Length@a, 1, {1, 1}]
fn5[a_] := ListConvolve[{1}, a, #] & /@ a
fn6[a_] := ArrayPad[a, {1, -1} (# - 1), "Periodic"] & /@ a

fn4@Range@4
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {4, 1, 2, 3}}

```
Equal @@ (Sort@#@Range@4 & /@ {fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6})
```

> True

```
First@AbsoluteTiming@Do[#@Range@500, {50}] & /@ {fn0, fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4, fn5, fn6} // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {{"fn0", "fn1", "fn2", "fn3", "fn4", "fn5", "fn6"}, None}] &
```

[image]

where `fn0[a_] := HankelMatrix[a, RotateRight@a]` is from ciao's answer.