# Mapping a function with levelspec vs. Mapping over a flattened list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have borrowed the following cyclic permutations list making function from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120264/cyclic-and-non-cyclic-permutations).

```
CyclicPermutations[list_] := Map[RotateRight[list, #] &, Range[Length[list]] - 1]
```

Using this function I make a list of cyclic permutations of the digits of some prime numbers as follows:

```
Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}]

{{{5, 4, 1}, {1, 5, 4}, {4, 1, 5}}, {{5, 4, 7}, {7, 5, 4}, {4, 7, 5}}}
```

Reconstructing the list of numbers using `Map[f,list,levelspec]` and `FromDigits` gives:

```
Map[FromDigits,Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}], 1]

{{514, 451, 145}, {574, 457, 745}}
```

The integers have been permuted again in the reconstruction. However, the following code does not permute them again at the cost of losing needed structure:

```
FromDigits/@Flatten[Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}], 1]

{541, 154, 415, 547, 754, 475}
```

I could partition this list properly but it would be very nice to keep the original nested structure.

**edit:**

I changed my function slightly to:

```
CyclicPermutations[list_]:=Table[RotateRight[list, n],{n, 1, Length[list]}]
```

An implementation of Project Euler # 35

```
count = 0;
Table[If[AllTrue[FromDigits/@CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]],PrimeQ],count+=1],{n, 1, 78498}];
count

55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` directly in your table. In your second line use:

```
Table[FromDigits /@ CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}]
```

> {{541, 154, 415}, {547, 754, 475}}

The issue with your `Map[FromDigits, ...]` solution is that you call `FromDigits` for a list of lists, instead of simple list of digits.  `FromDigits` seems to have some undocumented threading syntax:

```
FromDigits[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}]
```

> {1111, 2222, 3333}

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[FromDigits, Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}], {All, All}]
```

> `{{541, 154, 415}, {547, 754, 475}}`

`{All, All}` here means that `FromDigits` is applied to all elements in the second dimension. `{All, 1}` would apply it to the *first* element of all elements in in the second dimension. `{1, All}` would apply it to all of the elements of the first dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You can `Map`  `FromDigits[Transpose @ #] &` at level `1`:

```
Map[FromDigits[Transpose@#] &, 
 Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}], 1]
```

> {{541, 154, 415}, {547, 754, 475}}

Alternatively, you can `Map` `FromDigits`  at level `{2}`

```
Map[FromDigits, Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 
   101}], {2}]
```

> {{541, 154, 415}, {547, 754, 475}}

You can also use:

```
Map[FromDigits, Transpose /@ 
  Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}], 1]
```

> {{541, 154, 415}, {547, 754, 475}}

```
FromDigits[Transpose[#]] & /@ 
 Table[CyclicPermutations[IntegerDigits[Prime[n]]], {n, 100, 101}]
```

> {{541, 154, 415}, {547, 754, 475}}