# Converting integer to a triangular array

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I've been trying to write a function `toTriangle` which converts a given integer to a triangular array. For example:

```
toTriangle(123456)     = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}}
toTriangle(1010101010) = {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0}}
```

and so on. Naturally, this only works if the number of digits of the integer `n` is a triangular number. (that is, if $n = m(m+1)/2$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$.

I have written the following to try and implement this:

```
toTriangle := Function[n,
    len := 1/2 (Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength[n]] - 1);
    digits := IntegerDigits[n];
    triangle = {};
    For[i = 0, i < len; i++,
     AppendTo[triangle, Take[digits, n - i]];
     digits = Drop[digits, n - i];
    ];
    triangle
  ];
```

I have tried *dry running* the code bit by bit, and I noticed that it was the `Take[]` function which was causing the hassle; I suspect that you cannot give it a variable argument in position 2:

> `Take::seqs: Sequence specification (+n, -n, {+n}, {-n}, {m, n}, or {m, n, s}) expected at position 2 in Take[{1,2,3,4,5,6},i]. >>`

The same exact code I tested worked if I substituted `i` with some number. (directly, not by doing `/. i->3`). Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Some comments: You define global variables inside your function, consider using [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html). Is there any reason to define a pure function rather than `toTriangle[n_]:=...`? `AppendTo` and `For` are not "Mathematica like", you might want to try to bring the function into a more functional form

Comment: Somewhat related: [(29425)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29425/121), [(55659)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55659/121), [(56446)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56446/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you use `n` instead of `len` inside `Take` and `Drop`:

```
toTriangle := 
  Function[n,
   len := 1/2 (Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength[n]] - 1); 
   digits := IntegerDigits[n];
   triangle = {}; 
   For[i = 0, i < len, i++,
    AppendTo[triangle, Take[digits, len - i]];
    digits = Drop[digits, len - i];
   ];
   triangle
  ];

toTriangle[123456]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}} *)
```

For a solution that is more functional, see @kglr's solution.

Comment: You're right, but even when I switch it to `len` it renders `{ }` as an output.

Comment: The code you posted above also has a `;` instead of a `,` after `i++`. I didn't say anything because I assumed that was a typo of this version (given that the errors you show only occur when you put the `,` there)

Comment: Sorted - can't believe my mistake was a `;`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[toTriangleF]
toTriangleF = TakeList[IntegerDigits @ #, 
   Reverse @ Range[(Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength @ #] - 1)/2]] &;


toTriangleF /@ {123456, 1010101010}
```

> {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}}, {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0}}}

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `TakeLists`? I'm using version 10.

Comment: @LukeCollins, you can use ``Internal`PartitionRagged`` in place of `TakeList`.

Answer (score 3):

[Edit: It seems aardvark2012 beat me by 2 minutes using this exact approach - I'll leave this here for the moment as the explanation (although probably confusing) is more detailed in this answer]

Another solution without `TakeLists`, as requested:

```
toTriangle = Function[n, 
 First /@ Rest@
  FoldList[
   TakeDrop[#[[2]], #2] &,
   {{}, IntegerDigits@n}, 
   Reverse@Range[(Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength@n] - 1)/2]]
]
```

This works the following way:

- The function inside [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html) gets two arguments each time: The result from the previous step (starting with `{{}, IntegerDigits@n}`) and a number specifying how many elements to take off. The number comes from the list built by `Reverse@Range[(Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength@n] - 1)/2]]`
- The function, `TakeDrop[#[[2]], #2] &`, takes the second part of the first argument (which contains the remaining digits) and splits off the number specified by `#2`.
- After finishing the iteration, we drop the first element (which is `{{}, IntegerDigits@n}`), and take the first part of each of the remaining pairs. (Which is the part `Take`n by `TakeDrop` in each iteration)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
toTriangle[n_] := Module[{d = Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength[n]]-1},
    TakeList[IntegerDigits[n], Range[d/2, 1, -1]] /; IntegerQ[d]
]
```

If you have M11.1-, then use `` Internal`PartitionRagged `` instead of `TakeList`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `TakeLists`? I'm using version 10.

Answer (score 2):

@Mathe172's version seems to be a more direct way to improve your code. But in the interests of not using `For`, here are some possibilities that work on v10.4.

All of them are based on `FoldList`. The first uses `TakeDrop` to split the integer digits into the desired sublist and the remainder that will be subdivided further:

```
toTriangle1[n_] := 
 Module[{len = 1/2 (Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength[n]] - 1)}, 
  FoldList[TakeDrop[#1[[-1]], #2] &, {IntegerDigits[n]}, 
    Range[len, 1, -1]][[2 ;;, 1]]
  ]
```

The second modifies this with `Reap` and a kind of `SowDrop` function inside `FoldList`:

```
toTriangle2[n_] := 
 Module[{len = 1/2 (Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength[n]] - 1)},
  Reap[FoldList[(Sow[#1[[1 ;; #2]]]; Drop[#1, #2]) &, IntegerDigits@n,
      Reverse@Range[len]]][[-1, 1]]
  ]
```

The third calculates the index ranges for each sublist and then uses `Part` (`[[ ]]`) to extract them:

```
toTriangle3[n_] := 
 Module[{len = 1/2 (Sqrt[1 + 8 IntegerLength[n]] - 1), 
   listn = IntegerDigits[n]},
  listn[[#[[1]] ;; #[[2]]]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{Most[#], Rest[#] - 1} &@
     FoldList[#1 + #2 &, 1, Reverse@Range[len]]]
  ]
```

All of which give

```
toTriangle1 /@ {123456, 1010101010}
toTriangle2 /@ {123456, 1010101010}
toTriangle3 /@ {123456, 1010101010}

(* {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}}, 
    {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, using my `partitionBy` from [Partitioning with varying partition size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size/7808#7808):

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j};

partitionBy[Reverse@list, # &] ~Reverse~ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g}, {h, i}, {j}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using some *undocumented* functionality:

```
toTriangle[n_Integer] := Module[{l = IntegerLength[n]},
  MapIndexed[Drop[#, First[#2]] &, Most[
             Statistics`Library`VectorToUpperTriangularMatrix[IntegerDigits[n],
                                                              0, (Sqrt[8 l + 1] + 1)/2]]]]
```

For example,

```
toTriangle[1010101010]
   {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0}}
```