# position of rows (or columns) whose elements all satisfy a condition

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

How do I determine the position of rows whose entries all satisfy some condition (e.g., all elements of the row are positive)?  I've found out how to use `Select` to extract the correct rows, but I haven't been able to find out how to use Position to do the equivalent.

```
A = {{-1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {-7, 8, 9}}
Select[A, And @@ Thread[# > 0] &]
```

gives

```
{{4, 5, 6}}
```

but I want to know the position of that row (i.e. {2}).

Comment: `Position[And @@ Thread[# > 0] & /@ A, True]`?

Comment: wonderful.  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function `VectorQ`,

```
A = {{-1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {-7, 8, 9}};
Position[A, x_ /; VectorQ[x, # > 0 &], {1}]
```

or

```
Position[VectorQ[#, # > 0 &] & /@ A, True, {1}]
```

As Mr.Wizard points out that you should use a levelspec `{1}` to avoid testing subexpressions.

Comment: A good choice as `VectorQ` has early exit behavior, and does not unpack packed arrays. +1  (Edit: however, you should use a levelspec `{1}` to avoid testing subexpressions and losing this benefit.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard is there any nice thread what can unpack?

Comment: @Kuba You mean [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5258/121)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it seems so, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
aA = {{-1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {-7, 8, 9}};

Position[And @@ Thread[# > 0] & /@ aA, True]
(* {{2}} *)
```

Or, using the third argument of `Position` to set the *levelspec* to `1`:

```
Position[aA, _?(And @@ Thread[# > 0] &), 1]
(* {{2}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without `#`, yeah:

```
Position[A, {__?Positive}, {1}]
```

> ```
> {{2}}
> ```