# How to service preemptive computations while running a LibraryLink function?

Tags: dynamic, librarylink

[Cross-posted to Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/549468?p_p_auth=mVncNtd3)

---

The following is from the comparison between WSTP (MathLink) and LibraryLink in [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/Introduction.html):

> When the Wolfram Language is waiting for a WSTP application to return a result, it can be used to service preemptive computations such as those needed for user interface operations. When a library function is running this will not happen *without effort by the author of the library*.

<sup>(Emphasis by me.)</sup>

**What do I need to do to allow for preemptive computations to be serviced while running LibraryLink functions?**

Is there a function similar to `libData->AbortQ()` that I need to call from time to time?  `AbortQ()` itself won't allow for this (I already checked).  I did not find anything promising in `WolframLibrary.h`, but the documentation suggests that there should be a way.

---

**Update**

The following works, but I am not sure of its performance impact and I worry that this is just an abuse of functionality meant for something else.

Periodically execute the following in the LibraryLink function (the same way you would call `AbortQ()`)

```c
MLINK lp = libData->getMathLink(libData);
libData->processMathLink(lp);
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

[John Fultz has responded on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/549468).  It is sufficient to keep calling `libData->AbortQ()`.  Embarrassingly I must have made a mistake when testing this, as it does work.  I should note though that `AbortQ()` must be called frequently for it to be fluid, I originally only called it every second.