# Using Set without unpacking an array

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment, packed-arrays

I'm trying to optimise my code by making us of packed array.
However, it appears that using `Set` in combination with `Part` sometime unpacks the array, and sometimes leaves the array packed, even when the data you put in is of the same type.

When does `Set` unpack an array?

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Please give examples of cases when it unpacks.  It never unpacks for me when the type matches.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: `{1., 0., 0.}` is not packed. I suspect that if you give it packed, with ``Developer`ToPackedArray[{1., 0., 0.}]``, then `init` will remain packed. Can you try this?

Answer (score 4):

See [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48792/4330). The right hand side of the assignment has to be a packed array.