# Performance optimization of numerous simple but repetitive calculation

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm trying to speed up the calculation such like:

```
repeat=RandomChoice[{-1.,1.},1000000]
E^repeat
```

the calculation of `E^1.` is repetitive thus can be greatly accelerated if Mathematica stored the result and directly return the pre-calculated result when repetitive calls occurs.

Obviously `Once` cannot do this stuff as itself costs too much time, storing the result in some function also won't help as the function call already costs too much.

So the first question is:

**How to speed up such evaluation?**

When I'm trying to check whether Mathematica cached the result, I tried the following code:

```
dat = RandomChoice[{-1., 1.}, 10000000];
E^dat; // AbsoluteTiming

dat = RandomChoice[{-1., 1.}, 10000000] + RandomReal[{-1.*^-10, 1.*^-10}, 10000000];
E^dat; // AbsoluteTiming
```

However, to my surprise, the second one requires lot less computation time, why?

---

## Update

Oh, sorry that I forgot packing issues, so the only problem left is how to speed things up.

Answer (score 3):

**Removing overhead of an unpacked array**

The performance difference appears because `RandomChoice` produces an unpacked array, but your second command forces array packing. Large vector operations on packed arrays are much more efficient.

You can check packed/unpacked status of any array using:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[dat]
```

For your first example it gives `False` for the second `True`.

You can force array packing using `` Developer`ToPackedArray ``. In your example it will give large performance boost:

```
dat = Developer`ToPackedArray@RandomChoice[{-1., 1.}, 10000000];
E^dat; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.014406, Null}

More information on packed arrays:
[What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496),
[Guidelines for avoiding the unpacking of a packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/).

**Feasibility of caching**

Modern processors have built in instructions for calculating exponents. This means that recalculating exponent each time takes only one instruction, while searching in some sort of precalculated table will take much more instructions and will take longer.

If you have such a simple operation as exponent, there is no sense to organize software-defined caching mechanism. It is faster to recalculate than to lookup in a cache.

**Theoretical limit**

There is an *upper limit* of how many exponents a processor can evaluate in one second. Very roughly this can be estimated as `(processors frequency)x(number of cores)`. E.g. a 1 GHz 4-core processor can maximum perform 4x10^9 operations. This is without any overhead and ignoring that exponentiation takes more than one cycle.

When you look at `Timing` results of packed array operation above, you see that they are not far from the theoretical limit. This means that there is not much overhead left.

This means that the main strategy is to:

**Optimize your algorithm**

In your example you can first calculate exponents and then generate a list.

```
dat = Developer`ToPackedArray@RandomChoice[{Exp[-1.], Exp[1.]}, 10000000];
AbsoluteTiming[dat;]
```

In this case there will be no exponentiation step at all.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that……Thanks!

Comment: Oh, btw, still it didn't solve my original problem, how to speed up this process by some sort of caching?

Comment: @Wjx I have included some information about caching in the anwer.

Comment: but in C one can create an array of reference and simply calculate exponent twice and change the reference target, this will obviously be much faster. Are there any sort of memory sharing technique like this in MMA?

Comment: @Wjx ``RandomChoice[{Exp[-1.], Exp[1.]}, 10000000]`` calculates exponent exactly twice. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Wjx You can check it for example like this: ``myExp[x_] := (Print["Calculating exponent of x= ", x]; 
  Exp[x]); RandomChoice[{myExp[-1.], myExp[1.]}, 10000000];``

Comment: Unfortunately nope…… I need to calculate the exponent of a given list consists of a huge amouts of repetitive numbers.