# Trace of -{1} expression

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, evaluation, core-language, arithmetic

I'm trying to understand `Trace`. Usually it doesn't repeat but it adds `{-1,-1}` for his simple expression after having a correct result.

```
-{1}//Trace
```

> {-1, {-1}, {-1, -1}, {-1}}

Why `-{1}//Trace` is longer than `-Range[1]//Trace`?

Comment: You might find it more informative to use `TracePrint[]` instead.

Comment: Also `-{1} // Trace // FullForm` reveals some hidden structure.

Comment: @Shadowray, no, I want to make a function, that list argument `list_List` that is to be used as `-list`. as list is big, Trace is also. I don't know if I sould use other expression

Comment: @MichaelE2, `-Range[1]// Trace// FullForm` doesn't do transformations that first expression does. Why is it so?

Comment: I suspect it's because `Range[1]` produces a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) (``Developer`PackedArrayQ@Range[1]``), and they have different rules for evaluation than other lists. The difference is more apparent with longer lists, e.g. `-{1, 2}` vs. `-Range[2]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Are you going to make that an Answer?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Consider possibly including `Minus` for the sake of comparison.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  I considered it, but I think you have in mind something different than what I had in mind. The only difference, other than an alternative approach to coding negation, is that there is one less step in the evaluation, since the `-1` factor is unnecessary. But the speed seems the same. - I'm not sure what it is you see in the example. Consider answering yourself.  -- **Update:**  Okay, `Minus` seems faster on moderate sized arrays of integers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good question for uncovering an important difference between [***listability***](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) and ***vectorization***.  Sometimes these terms are used interchangeably, but I would like to make a technical distinction.  In both `Listable` and vectorized functions, the value of the function on a list is equal to values of the function on each element of the list.  From the theoretical point of view of a function is defined by its values, there is no difference, but on practical grounds, there is a difference in how efficiently a function is computed.  A function is ***vectorized*** if it treats a vector (or array) as if it were atomic.  The ability to do this depends on the architecture of the CPU; it is implemented in *Mathematica* by packed arrays (see [this technical note](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/391/) by Rob Knapp, [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/)).  Generally speaking, when a packed array is passed to a function that is not vectorized, the array will be *unpacked* (search the site, or perhaps [start here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/are-there-guidelines-for-avoiding-the-unpacking-of-a-packed-array)).

The difference one sees in the `Trace` of `-{1}` and `-Range[1]` is due to `Range[n]` being a packed array.  For the most part, the difference between the listability and vectorization is invisible to the user.  One sees it mainly speed, memory usage, and in this case the evaluation sequence exposed by `Trace`.  One can also test whether a list is a packed array with `` Developer`PackedArrayQ ``. One can trace unpacking with `On["Packing"]`. Aside these tools, I do not think that it is possible for a user to define a function of the form `f[...] :=...` that is both `Listable` and vectorized; the user's only option is to write a non-`Listable` function in terms of built-in vectorized functions or use `Compile` (or perhaps write a [`LibraryFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunction.html)).  In other words, if one sets `SetAttributes[f, Listable]`, the listability attribute is applied first: `f[{x1, x2,...}]` becomes `{f[x1], f[x2],...}` before `f` is evaluated, which will unpack a packed array. But in the OP's example, with `Times`, which is `Listable`, this does not happen.  It is similar with `Plus` and other vectorized functions.  It must be that there are internal rules that are applied for such functions, shadows of which show up in `Trace`, but which are not explained in the documentation (AFAIK).

We can see the above in the OP's examples.  One gets a more complete picture of the evaluation sequence with `Trace[expr, TraceOriginal -> True]` (`TracePrint`, mentioned by @J.M., also shows more).  Even further, the differences are somewhat more convincing comparing the examples `-{1, 2}` and `-Range[2]`.  But I deal with the OP's examples and let the reader explore the rest.

In `-{1}`, the `Listable` attribute is applied first, the first two steps of `-{1} // Trace`:

```
Times[-1, List[1]]
List[Times[-1, 1]]
```

In `-Range[1]`, the vectorization can be seen in the transformation from the third to fourth step:

```
Times[-1, List[1]]
List[-1]]
```

What is invisible is that `List[1]`, the result of `Range[1]` is a packed array, whereas `List[1]`, the "result" of `{1}`, is not.  This difference may be verified by executing the following:

```
{1} // Developer`PackedArrayQ
Range[1] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
```

One can see the same listability step applied if `Range[1]` is unpacked, which can be done with the function `` Developer`FromPackedArray ``:

```
-Developer`FromPackedArray@Range[1] // Trace
```

*Addendum: Help with reading `Trace` output.*

[WReach's `traceView2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence/29340#29340) is a wonderful function for presenting the evaluation sequence.

Here is another function for formatting `Trace` output. The output consists of nested lists corresponding to the depth of the evaluation stack.  The following indicates each level by grouping and indenting its items.

```
Clear[fmt, ifmt];
fmt[x_] := Block[{fmt`step = 0}, ifmt[x]];
ifmt[s_List] := Row[
   {Style[RawBoxes@"{", SpanMaxSize -> Infinity],
    " ",
    Column[ifmt /@ s]}];
ifmt[x_] := Row@{Style[++fmt`step, Italic, "Label"], ". ", FullForm /@ x};
```

Op's examples:

```
-List[1] // Trace // fmt
```

[image]

```
-Range[1] // Trace // fmt
```

[image]

`Trace[expr]` omits some steps of the evaluation such as the `Head` of each expression.  `Trace[expr, TraceOriginal -> True]` shows more.

*Exercises.*

Compare these with each other and with the ordinary trace above.

```
Trace[-List[1], TraceOriginal -> True] // fmt
Trace[-Range[1], TraceOriginal -> True] // fmt
```

Examine these (I think the difference between listability and vectorization is even more obvious):

```
Trace[-List[1, 2], TraceOriginal -> True] // fmt
Trace[-Range[2], TraceOriginal -> True] // fmt
```