# Reap unpacks packed arrays

Tags: packed-arrays, packing, sow-reap

I noticed that `Reap` unpacks packed arrays. I've looked at [previous answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/are-there-guidelines-for-avoiding-the-unpacking-of-a-packed-array) but am still an unsure whether this a serious issue.

E.g. consider [Ex 47.3 from EIWL](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/47-debugging-your-code.html#i-14):

Use `Sow` and `Reap` to get a list of all cases where `#/2` is used in `Nest[If[EvenQ[#], #/2, 3#+1]&, 1000, 20]`.

One solution is

```
On["Packing"]
Reap @ Nest[If[EvenQ[#], Sow[#]/2, 3#+1]&, 1000, 20]
```

but one gets multiple (`FromPackedArray`) messages about unpacking arrays due, I assume, to the fact that intermediate results are irregular structures.

Since other users don't appear to see this, here's a screenshot:

[image: FromPackedArray messages]

BTW, since $3x+1$ is always even, a more efficient coding of the Collatz problem is to replace `3#+1` by `(3#+1)/2`.

Comment: OTOH, ``coll = Reap[Nest[If[EvenQ[#], Sow[#]/2, 3 # + 1] &, 1000, 20]]; coll[[-1, 1]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ`` returns `True`.

Comment: I get no messages about packing (or unpacking) from the central block of code in *Mathematica* 10.1.

Comment: Ditto no messages in V11.1.1.

Comment: No message in v9.0.1

Comment: You are using `TraditionalForm` as your default output format, and creating those boxes is generating the unpacking messages. For example, adding a `;` at the end of the `Reap` will prevent the messages (until you display the output).

Comment: So _should_ using `TraditionalForm` as the default output format do that? Perhaps a more useful `FromPackedArray` message would have been helpful here.

Comment: Even in `StandardForm` I get the similar behaviour with `Reap@Plot[x,{x,0,1},EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]];`.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Posting the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146610/reap-unpacks-packed-arrays#comment394172_146610) by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) as an answer:</sub>

You are using `TraditionalForm` as your default output format, and creating those boxes is generating the unpacking messages. For example, adding a `;` at the end of the `Reap` will prevent the messages (until you display the output).

Proof:

```
On["Packing"]
ToBoxes[RandomReal[1, 10], TraditionalForm];
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to LeafCount. >>