# Unpacking array message in Compile and Fold

Tags: memory, packed-arrays

Suppose, I have a nonlinear map, like this:

```
m1 = Compile[{{n, _Real}, {k2, _Real}, {k3, _Real}, {x, _Real, 1}},
{x[[1]] Cos[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)] + 10. x[[2]] Sin[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)], 
x[[2]] Cos[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)] - 0.1 x[[1]] Sin[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)] - 
k2 (x[[1]] Cos[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)] + 10. x[[2]] Sin[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)])^2 - 
k3 (x[[1]] Cos[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)] + 10. x[[2]] Sin[2. \[Pi] (0.663 + n)])^3}, 
CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

I turned `On["Packing"]`.

Just after evaluation I see warnings from MMA about "Unpackung array with dimensions {21}", then other "dimensions", then "Unpacking array with dimensions {1} in call to Flatten", etc. What does this mean?

I use this `m1` inside `FoldList`. The problem is that this `FoldList` function has great memory consumption. So I decided it might be related to using unpacked arrays and used `On["Packing"]` to check.

The main function is:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{Sqrt[10^-5 10.], Sqrt[10^-5/10.]}, 0], 100000];

With[{n = 0.004, k2 = 0.25, k3 = -1., t = 10000, nt = 1000},
 Block[{mo = Transpose[{PadLeft[Range[0., n, n/t], t + nt + 1, 0.], 
  PadRight[Range[0., k2, k2/nt], t + nt + 1, k2], 
  PadRight[Range[0., k3, k3/nt], t + nt + 1, k3]}], rp},
  rp = Reap[
  FoldList[(Sow[Count[UnitStep[(#[[;; , 1]] - 0.05)], 1]]; 
    m1[#2[[1]], #2[[2]], #2[[3]], 
     Pick[#, UnitStep[(#[[;; , 1]] - 0.05) (#[[;; , 1]] + 0.05)], 0]]) &, data, mo]][[2, 1]]]]
```

Running this function also gives warnings about unpacking. I'm not sure unpacking affects memory consumption, but my main goal is to optimize this function in terms of time and memory. Now what I see in Windows task manager is ~10GB memory of MMA when this function finished.

**ADD**

OK, more simple question. Why this does not unpack:

```
Compile[{{x,_Real}},{{Cos@x, Sin@x},{-x^2,x}}]
```

and this one displays warning about unpacking:

```
Compile[{{x,_Real}},{{Cos@x, Sin@x},{-Sin@x,Cos@x}}].
```

I do not understand, for me these two `Compile` are the same, what is the difference?

`InputForm` for the first example gives clean code, but for the second one it contains

```
Function[{x}, Block[{Compile`$10}, Compile`$10 = Cos[x]; {{Compile`$10, x}, 
{-Sin[x], Compile`$10}}]], Evaluate
```

Why `Cos[x]` is inside `Block` and `Function`, why not `Sin[x]` as well?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5258

Comment: @MichaelE2, OK, and...? What to do in my specific case?

Comment: Analyze your code? :) Seriously, "Related: link" comments might, or not, help solve the problem. While they might help the asker, especially if they didn't know the related knowledge, another function they serve to help those with a similar problem to track down relevant ideas through the "Linked Question" list on the right. In your case, they seem to answer the points you raised, "What does this mean?" and "I'm not sure unpacking affects memory consumption." Given that and that I don't have time to analyze your code myself at the moment (sorry about that), I hoped they would help you.

Comment: There are many site users who probably can answer your main question, and with luck, someone will.  I was just trying to add the little bit I could, since I knew of these Q&A.

Comment: The unpacking messages generated during the _compilation_ of m1 are not so relevant. They occur during some processing for optimizing expressions, generating and compiling C code etc. What happens when running the already compiled function is more important.

Comment: @ilian, thanks for comment. What about my main part of the question, do you have ideas/advices?

Comment: Count definitely unpacks, perhaps some improvement can be obtained by replacing Count[UnitStep[...], 1] with Total[UnitStep[...]]]

Comment: @ilian, thanks, I will try.