# Packed/Unpacked array - what object/like 0 or 1?/how to check/

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, built-in-symbols, packed-arrays

In Mathematica, there is a concept called packed array.

```
In[1]:= ClearAll[A, B, L1, L2, L3, L4];
A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
   19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30};
B = Range[30];
L1 = Developer`FromPackedArray[A];
L2 = Developer`ToPackedArray[A];
L3 = Developer`FromPackedArray[B];
L4 = Developer`ToPackedArray[B];

In[2]:= A === B === L1 === L2 === L3 === L4

Out[2]= True

In[3]:= {ByteCount[A], ByteCount[B], ByteCount[L1], ByteCount[L2], 
 ByteCount[L3], ByteCount[L4]}

Out[3]= {768, 360, 768, 360, 768, 360}
```

1. For what Mathematica objects, does the concept of 'packed/unpacked' exist?
   (only for `List`?)
2. We can define compression method (7z/zip/tar/...) or compression level (store/very fast/fast/normal...) for archive utility like 7-zip. Likewise, are there various degrees/methods/kinds of packing in Mathematica? Or it is just 'packed or unpacked' like '0 or 1'.
3. How can we check/verify a Mathematica object is packed/unpacked ? (+ inspect the degree/methods/kinds)

I have more questions :

4. Does `` Developer`FromPackedArray `` do nothing for unpacked array ?
5. Does `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` do nothing for packed array ?
6. Are there any option for `` Developer`FromPackedArray ``/`` Developer`ToPackedArray `` ?
7. Are there any other function that can change the state of packed/unpacked (or degrees/methods/kinds) ?

Comment: Surprisingly it has been documented [```Developer`ToPackedArray```](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/ToPackedArray.html)/[```Developer`FromPackedArray```](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/FromPackedArray.html). `ToPackedArray` seem to have at least `type` and `Tolerance` options. For checking (+ type and rank) you can use [```Developer`PackedArrayQ```](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PackedArrayQ.html). As noted "successfully pack full lists of any depth containing integer/real/complex numbers".

Comment: And "If expr is not a packed array, `FromPackedArray[expr]` returns expr unchanged".

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array -- by "array" whether packed or unpacked is meant a list (vector), a rectangular list of lists (matrix), or higher-rank tensor. "Packed" is applied only to arrays (currently).

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5258/are-there-guidelines-for-avoiding-the-unpacking-of-a-packed-array

Comment: Thank you, now I knew something, I want to write something(the answer) in my question if I have time, but only helpful for beginner.