# Hold attributes vs performance

Tags: performance-tuning, functional-style, guidelines

Is there a reason to use `Hold*` attributes for functional code (e.g. no intention to mutate input)? I'd expect performance gains as in pass by value vs pass by reference.

E.g.

```
data = RandomReal[1, 10^8];

data // Function[x, x[[1]]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {8.*10^-7, 0.0372378}
> ```

```
data // Function[x, x[[1]], HoldAllComplete] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {8.0*10^-7, 0.0372378}
> ```

The question is, why doesn't it matter? Or are there cases where it matters, performance tuning wise.

Due to my limited understanding of internals of WL implementation I am puzzled by this and I often have a case where I need to traverse a big expression by keeping a 'reference' to the expression as a whole. So I can do:

```
parse[bigExpression]:=parse[bigExpression, #] & /@ bigExpression
```

or I can make `parese` a `HoldFirst`. Or I could even `MapIndexed` and keep track of the index I could use to access a global `bigExpression`.

### Edit:

As noted in comments, the initial example wasn't the best, here I hope is a better one:

```
data = RandomReal[1, 10^8];

g1[x_] := x[[1]];
f1[x_] := g1[x];

SetAttributes[{g2, f2}, HoldAll];
g2[x_] := x[[1]];
f2[x_] := g2[x];
f1[data] // RepeatedTiming
f2[data] // RepeatedTiming
%%/%
```

> {8.38*10^-7, 0.487565}
>
> {7.840*10^-7, 0.487565}
>
> {1.07, 1.}

Comment: Good question. But I'm not entirely sure that your test is too meaningful... If I increase the size of `data`, I don't see any change in the timings. I've also tried to unpack the array and to use symbols with downvalues, without any clear influence on the result.

Comment: For your information, Mathematica does **not** use the concepts of pass by value versus pass by reference. See question [156319](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156319)

Comment: Isn't this a case of `Function` simply being well-optimized for this sort of thing? Also, you can get a bit of a speedup if you use `Slot` instead (`Function[Null, #[[1]], HoldAllComplete]`)

Comment: @LukasLang I appreciate better examples, this was the simplest that came to my mind.

Comment: Also, I believe that there are times when using the `Hold` attribute prevents mathematica from copying data, which can be important when working with large datasets when there is a risk of running out of RAM or hitting the swap memory limit. However, I found it difficult to find good examples of this.

Comment: @Somos I am not sure what concept it uses but if you write your code in a sloppy way 'copying' will make it slower.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I was able to reproduce this confusion with DownValues as well but Function was quicker to show.

Comment: The documentation for `HoldAllComplete[]` has an example using the Hofstadter-Conway sequence which shows why it is sometimes faster to use it.

Comment: I thought Mathematica tried to be clever about only copying on modifications...but I guess I am not certain of that. Obviously one place`Hold*` will help a lot regardless is if you do lots of manipulations. Think passing a huge area through `OptionsPattern` and `Merge`-ing the results and things. There passing in a `Hold[localVar$nn]` has in the past bought me huge speed ups.

Comment: @b3m2a1 gimme best practices applicable to general audience :) Anyway, how isn't this question 'hot'. Why isn't there a penalty in hold vs non hold?

Comment: @Kuba if I can think up some I will

Comment: As b3m2a1 pointed out, _Mathematica_ uses layz copying. This why I think that `Hold`-Attributes give you the edge only if you want to modify data _in place_. Then it will safe you a couple of copy operations and, probably more importantly, a lot of memory allocation and deallocation under the hood. `Hold`-attributes also disable pattern matching which can also be a reason why, at times `Hold`-Attributes might result in faster code: They enforce you to aviod complicated patterns in a function definition.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Those are important notes and I think the one about modification of data is counter intuitive. Your comment is along of what I am trying to  achieve here.

Comment: I think the distinction that you are expecting will only be apparent in the presence of computationally expensive delayed definitions.  For instance, the second example but with `data = ...` changed to `data := ...`.  For immediate definitions with inert values, the computational time of the extra evaluations is vanishing small.

Comment: @WReach thanks, though I think it is an objectively intuitive behavior. I think my question boils down to not understanding well the concept of an 'inert expression' you mentioned and which appears sparsely in SE answers.

Comment: @WReach now I even vaguely recall a topic where someone was discussing how expressions internally keep information about being evaluated' already during current evaluation''.

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand why you think there will be a difference in timing for your example. In both cases the head is evaluated, the data variable is evaluated, the [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function) is evaluated, and then the [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) is evaluated. It's just a matter of order. Let's take a smaller example so that we can follow the trace:

```
data = RandomReal[1, 3];

f1 = Function[x, x[[1]]];
f2 = Function[x, x[[1]], HoldAllComplete];
```

The first example trace:

```
Trace[data //f1]
```

> ```
> {
> {f1,Function[x,x[[1]]]},
> {data,{0.717387,0.557898,0.102441}},
> Function[x,x[[1]]][{0.717387,0.557898,0.102441}],
> {0.717387,0.557898,0.102441}[[1]],
> 0.717387
> }
> ```

*(the HoldForm wrappers have been suppressed)*

Notice how the head is evaluated, data is evaluated, the [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function) is evaluated, and then finally [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) is evaluated.

The second example:

```
Trace[data //f2]
```

> ```
> {
> {f2,Function[x,x[[1]],HoldAllComplete]},
> Function[x,x[[1]],HoldAllComplete][data],
> data[[1]],
> {data,{0.717387,0.557898,0.102441}},
> {0.717387,0.557898,0.102441}[[1]],
> 0.717387
> }
> ```

In this case, the head is evaluated, the [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function) is evaluated, data is evaluated, and then [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) is evaluated. The [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete) attribute only changes the order of evaluation, it doesn't eliminate any evaluations.

Comment: You are right, my example was too minimal. I added a new one.

Answer (score 5):

In general, as Henrik and I note in the comments, Mathematica makes sure only to copy data when it has undergone some sort of change internally. An easy way to see this is to set a flag like `Valid` and see when it disappears:

```
myBigData = RandomReal[{}, {500, 800}];
myBigData // System`Private`SetValid;

amIDifferentNowHeld[Hold[data_]] :=
 ! System`Private`ValidQ[data]
amIDifferentNow[data_] :=
 ! System`Private`ValidQ[data]

amIDifferentNow[myBigData]

False

amIDifferentNowHeld[Hold[myBigData]]

False

trueCopy[data_] :=
  BinaryDeserialize[BinarySerialize[data]];

amIDifferentNow[trueCopy[myBigData]]

True
```

So it seems pretty clear to me that we were working with the same object in both the unheld and held cases and this is why you can pass big arrays and stuff through a program and not need to worry about pass-by-value or pass-by-reference. It's really all pass-by-reference anyway with a pointer to some kind of internal `Expression` object.

Now, where `Hold` *does* buy you something is in data-safety. Consider this kind of naive data cleaning you might think to do (basically copied from some old code I wrote). I wanted to canonicalize some options and merge with some defaults so that they were a nice single `Association` I could store and query later and feed through my program. Here's how that looked:

```
$defaults = {
   {
    "GridOptions" -> {"Domain" -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, "Points" -> {60, 60}},
    "PotentialEnergyOptions" -> {"PotentialFunction" -> (1/2 #^2 &)},
    "KineticEnergyOptions" -> {"Masses" -> {1, 1}, "HBars" -> {1, 1}}
    }
   };
Options[doADVR] = {
   "KineticEnergyMatrix" -> None,
   "PotentialEnergyMatrix" -> None
   };
getWfs[ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

 Module[{dom, pts, potF, m, hb, ke, pe, opts},
  opts = Merge[
    {
     Normal@{ops},
     $defaults
     },
    First
    ];
  (* do the real calculation, usually, but that's not the point here *)

  opts
  ]
```

And here's what happens when you feed in a `SparseArray` for one of the `"*Matrix"` arguments:

```
ke = $H4DDVR["KineticEnergy", "Points" -> {30, 30}];

ke // Head
ke // Dimensions

SparseArray

{900, 900}

dvrOpts = getWfs["KineticEnergyMatrix" -> ke];

dvrOpts["KineticEnergyMatrix"] // Head
dvrOpts["KineticEnergyMatrix"] // Dimensions

List

{900, 900}
```

We can see that `Normal` converted it to a `List`! As these things grow in size the penalty for that gets more and more dramatic.

And Mathematica provides lots of ways for you to shoot yourself in the foot like this: `Normal` recurses into data structures, `ReplaceAll` digs into even `PackedArray` structures, etc. and those are the *well designed* functions. Too much of the system tries to be "clever" or "helpful" and in doing so makes it really easy to wreck your data by accident.

Obviously `Hold` has its core usage in clever destructing-based meta-programming, but in terms of *performance* a big place `Hold` can help you out is in making sure your data flows through a program unadulterated, e.g.:

```
dvrOpts["KineticEnergyMatrix"] // Head
ReleaseHold@dvrOpts["KineticEnergyMatrix"] // Head
ReleaseHold@dvrOpts["KineticEnergyMatrix"] // Dimensions

Hold

SparseArray

{900, 900}
```

I'd say the place where I actually use `Hold` the most is when doing crazy things with like `Block` to ensure no evaluation, though, which often look like:

```
doASymbolicThing~SetAttributes~HoldAll
$defaultSymbolList = Thread@Hold[{x, y, z, a, b, c}];
doASymbolicThing[symbolicExpr_, 
  symbols1 : {__Symbol}, 
  symbol2_Symbol
  ] :=
 Replace[
  Thread[
   DeleteDuplicates@
    Join[Thread[Hold[symbols1]], $defaultSymbolList, {Hold[symbol2]}],
   Hold
   ],
  Hold[symList : {__Symbol}] :>
   Block[symList,
    processSymbolicExprSafely[symbolicExpr, symList]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: How would `amIDifferentNow` be different from `amIDifferentNowHeld`? `ValidQ` does not have any hold attributes, so `data` would evaluate anyway before `ValidQ` sees it, right? Shouldn't you use `ValidQ[Unevaluated[data]]` in `amIDifferentNowHeld`?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit This is true. The effect will be the same (in that there is no effect) but you're right that if I _expected_ a difference that wouldn't have picked it up.

Comment: With these new definitions, `amIDifferentNowHeld[Hold[myBigData]]` returns `True` for me.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit ah right because it's testing the raw `Symbol` `myBigData`...I think the former definition _was_ what I wanted because it's saying "Does `Hold` do anything?" and the answer to that is "No it doesn't touch the underlying data and 're-evaluating' that data also does nothing"

Comment: Aren't you assuming that copying would strip 'valid' flag? If so, is it a safe assumption?

Comment: @Kuba yeah but I believe I have seen that in the past. These flags are pretty much `Expression` specific I think.

Comment: @b3m2a1 maybe, maybe not :) I think we need a better statement than an assumption about an undocumented feature :)

Comment: @Kuba you can test it with `ExpressionStore`. Use the same object as a key both before and after sending it through a function. That works by raw object identity, so that will tell you if the pointer has changed at all or not. In that case I can tell you there is absolutely no change as I make use of this in my code and so does, e.g. Jason Biggs