# Compile and "True should be a machine-size real number..." Error

Tags: compile, return-value

I am trying to compile a little summation function.
As far as I understand, because the built-in `Sum` function can also return `NaN` objects I have to make sure only numbers get out before returning.

```
X = Compile[{}, (
   result = Sum[i, {i, 10}];
   If[NumberQ[result], Return[result], Abort[]];
   )];
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following two warnings...

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression True should be a machine-size real number.
>   CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 2; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

I guess the glitch is in the `NumberQ` function and its return type.

Any ideas on how to handle this issue correctly and effectively?

**EDIT:**

When I omit the check for numeric values while inserting a Return[] statement Mathematica falls back to the uncompiled version (warning: Compile::cret).

Answer (score 6):

For the error handling use the compilers error handling mechanism:

```
cffail = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Exp[x], 
   "RuntimeOptions" -> {"RuntimeErrorHandler" -> Function[$Failed]}];
cffail[{1000.}]
```

The Function can be anything (Throw[..],...).

For the summation you could use Total in stead:

```
Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x]]
```

Comment: Even though there doesn't seem to be any call to `MainEvaluate`, I didn't notice any difference in execution speed on my system between: `tot = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x]] ; Timing[tot[RandomInteger[4, 100000000]]]` and `Timing[Total[RandomReal[4, 100000000]]]`. I'm not sure why, but `Total` applied to integers seemed to be about 15% quicker than applied to reals.

Comment: @image_doctor, I am not sure what you are trying to say here. I wanted to point out that `Total` will be faster than `Sum`. Also, as a side note, `AbsoluteTiming` is better suited for than `Timing`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `AbsoluteTiming`. I'm not always sure about what I'm saying either :) Perhaps it was that in this context, with `Total` and other 'simple' functions there is little if any advantage to using a compiled function, it may be that  `Total` is already quite well optimised. I can see there is a difference between using `Sum` and `Total`. `Total` sums an existing list of numbers whereas `Sum` needs to construct an iteration across a range of not yet existing values, perhaps this means that they can't be compared directly.

Comment: @image_doctor Compiled `Total` is just a direct call to the kernel function `TotalAll`, which is probably the same one used to implement the ordinary `Total` for machine number inputs. In regard to why `Total` of integers is faster than reals: memory bandwidth. Reals are twice the size of integers.

Comment: @OleksandrR Interesting, I was assuming that RandomInteger, which I used to generate the list to be summed, returned Mathematica arbitrary length exact integers as this is what is described in the "Types of Numbers" tutorial.  So I thought they would consume more space than a machine sized reals. So does this mean exact integers are dynamic in size, or that RandomInteger and presumably other functions, return a machine sized integer type?

Comment: @OleksandrR OK, with a little investigation, I've answered my own question. The integers are variable in size, so runtime depends on the actual values of the integers. We live and learn :)

Comment: @image_doctor, the big int / machine int conversion takes place automatically when needed and transparent to the user. When possible machine arithmetic is tried for performance reasons (speed/memory).

Comment: @ruebenko Thanks, so there are run time checks on each calculation to spot overflow and the type of call required to operate on the variable type of integer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having to read between the lines because you did not fully specify your problem, however I suspect that you need to use the third argument of [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html).

```
func =
  Compile[{{length}},
   (result = Sum[i^2, {i, length}]; If[NumberQ[result], result, Abort[]]),
   {{NumberQ[_], True | False}}
  ]

func[5]
```

> ```
> 55.
> ```

Comment: Although if you look at the result of CompilePrint, you will see that this is not very efficient, since sum is not compiled, but just called using MainEvaluate.

Answer (score 2):

Are you definitely sure you need the error checking for NaN inside `Compile`? 
The error checking seems to generate very inefficient compiled code. It basically only calls `MainEvaluate`, so you gain nothing by compiling.

```
data = Range[1000];
func /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
func1 /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.1280073, Null} *)

(* ==> {0.0140008, Null} *)

func = 
  Compile[{{length}}, (result = Sum[i^2, {i, length}]; 
    If[NumberQ[result], result, Abort[]]), {{NumberQ[_], 
     True | False}}];
func1 = Compile[{{length, _Integer}}, Sum[i^2, {i, length}]];

data = Range[1000];
d1 = func /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
d2 = func1 /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
d1 == d2

(* ==> {0.1160067, Null} *)

(* ==> {0.0140008, Null} *)

(* ==> True *)

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[func]
CompilePrint[func1]

(*
==> "
        1 argument
        1 Boolean register
        4 Integer registers
        7 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        I1 = 0
        R3 = 0.
        Result = R2

1   V17 = MainEvaluate[                                  2
Function[{length}, result = Sum[i , {i, length}]][ R0]]
2   B0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{length}, NumberQ[result]][ R0]]
3   if[ !B0] goto 7
4   R5 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{length}, result][ R0]]
5   R2 = R5
6   goto 9
7   R1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{length}, Abort[]][ R0]]
8   R2 = R1
9   Return
"
*)

(*
==> "
        1 argument
        9 Integer registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        I0 = A1
        I3 = 0
        Result = I4

1   I4 = I3
2   I5 = I0
3   I7 = I3
4   goto 8
5   I6 = Square[ I7]
6   I8 = I4 + I6
7   I4 = I8
8   if[ ++ I7 < I5] goto 5
9   Return
"
*)
```

So my recommendation is to skip the check (what could generate the NaN in such a simple sum anyway?) or check for NaN values outside the compiled function.

Comment: But when I run your "func1" the result I get is Null. At the moment I use the Return[] statement it falls back to the uncompiled version because "the return types in the Sum statement are different (Compile::cret)"...

Comment: Works fine for me. func1[55] returns 56980. Which mma version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid your base assumption here is false, and the sum compiles much better **without** this call to `NumberQ`. See:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`;
func = Compile[{{length, _Integer}}, (
    Sum[i^2, {i, 1, length}]
    )];
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[func]
```

The output of `CompilePrint` shows that the sum is performed without any call to `MainEvaluate`, which you absolutely want to avoid if you to [compile efficiently](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1803/700).

Comment: As a side note, this uses the compiled version up to parameters values of around 1870 when, I guess, numerical overflow causes it to switch back to the uncompiled version.