# Compile recursive function modifying global variables

Tags: compile, recursion, scoping

How to compile recursive formula when it relies on more than a few global variables (global to the topmost compiled function)? It is unreasonable to pass on all such variables to each recursive subroutine (there are more than one), as:

- that would require a lot of tensor copying which would cause a slowdown;
- even if passing globals would be possible, returning all affected globals from each subroutine would be tedious as each function must return a regular tensor of uniform data type.

Consider the following toy problem to calculate the factorial:

```
fact[x_] := Module[{sub, global = 1},
   sub[y_] := If[y > 0, global = global*y; sub[y - 1]];
   sub@x;
   global];
```

How to compile it without passing `global` to `sub`? While this code works nicely in the general *Mathematica* interface, the following compiled version will call `MainEvaluate` as there is a `SetDelayed` expression which the compiler cannot handle:

```
factC = Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, Module[{global = 1, sub},
    sub[y_] := If[y > 0, global = global*y; sub[y - 1]];
    sub@x;
    global]];
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Related mathgroup post: [Pass by reference for compiled functions](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/EcVmyZihWNM/J-FGt7NY9pcJ) No solution general enough though.

Comment: @ssch This pretty much tells me that what I want is impossible at the moment. I might be more successful writing code directly in C and than calling from under *Mathematica*...

Comment: Yea :( Perhaps passing the globals in the `Compiled` functions and then replace them with pointers in the `CCodeStringGenerate` can save some (writing) time.