# How to return the rhs of a transformation rule from within Compile[]

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, compile

I have defined the following function:

```
g = Compile[{{x0, _Real}},
    sol = NSolve[
        Rationalize[CDF[ExponentialDistribution[1], x] == x0, 10^-10],
        {x}, Reals];
   sol]
```

Running `g[0.5]` it fails with:

> In[460]:= g[0.5]
>
> During evaluation of In[460]:= CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled
>   expression {{x->0.693147}} should be a machine-size integer. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[460]:= CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not
>   complete external evaluation at instruction 2; proceeding with
>   uncompiled evaluation. >>
>
> Out[460]= {{x -> 0.693147}}

If I try to extract the rhs from the transformation rule with `sol[[1,1,2]]` I get the following error:

> Compile::part: Part specification sol[[1,1,2]] cannot be compiled
>   since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will
>   use the uncompiled function. >>
>
> Compile::part: Part specification {{x->0.693147}}[[1,1,2]] cannot be
>   compiled since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank.
>   Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>

How could I let `Compile[]` know that I intend to return `{{a -> b}}` or how could I extract the rhs of the transformation rule and return that only?

**EDIT**: It appears that none of my functions (`Rationalize[]`, `NSolve[]`, `ExponentialDistribution[]`) is "compilable" based on [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) by @MichaelE2.

Comment: See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) and perhaps [these, too](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compile).  I don't think you can compile your expression, and you might want to read up on how `Compile` works.

Comment: Here's another good one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively

Answer (score 1):

Just some observations (which may be counter the intention):
1. You could use in-built function: `Quantile`:

```
qf[x_] := Quantile[ExponentialDistribution[1], x]
```

`qf[0.5]` yields 0.693147

The uncompiled function could be done:

```
func[x0_] := 
 First[x /. 
   Quiet@NSolve[CDF[ExponentialDistribution[1], x] == x0, x, Reals]]
```

In the preceding I have not used `Rationalize. I was uncertain what the aim of its use was. If the aim is to express the quantile as a raitonal approximation than it can be applied post. If it was to aid calculation the compiled version seems problematic to me.

Comment: Thanks for the `Quantile[]` hint @ubpdqn! I will try it and it see if it speeds things up, because otherwise my function is veeery slow :( It takes ~2 secs for 200 samples.

Comment: @Zet There is also `InverseCDF[ExponentialDistribution[1], x0]`, which probably has the same underlying function as `Quantile` for a distribution.