# Why is my compiled function slower than a regular function?

Tags: compile

I have the following functions:

```
Block[{n, diag},
 snake`diag[n_] = Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])];
 snake`alongdiag[n_, diag_] = {0, diag + 1} + (n - diag (diag - 1)/2) {1, -1};
 snake[n_] = snake`alongdiag[n, snake`diag[n]];]
(*A003986 on OEIS, http://oeis.org/A003986*)
A003986[n_] := BitOr @@ (snake[n] - {1, 1})
A003986c = 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, A003986[n], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

The functions seem very "compilable" in that they're just numerical computations.  However, the compiled function performs as badly or worse:

```
Table[{x, A003986 /@ Range@(10^x); // Timing // First, 
     A003986c[Range@(10^x)]; // Timing // First}, {x, 5}]~
  Prepend~{"Func", "ME", "Comp"} // TableForm
```

[image]

Fine - perhaps the function does "too little" and the overhead from running the C code is costing too much. But then altering my code to fix that doesn't help things:

```
A003986l = 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, A003986 /@ Range[n], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
Table[{x, A003986 /@ Range@(10^x); // Timing // First, 
     A003986l[(10^x)]; // Timing // First}, {x, 5}]~
  Prepend~{"Func", "ME", "Comp"} // TableForm
```

[image]

Both functions are approximately linear, so everything seems to be working as expected in an algorithmic regard, but this is very slow for a couple of formulas and `BitOr`! What is going wrong?

Comment: Try ``CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint``  on `A003986c` -- I bet it shows a `MainEvaluate`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Okay. Why doesn't it display the usual warning "Proceding with ME..." if it does?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Huh, it did... I'll see how I can fix that. Why wouldn't it compile?

Comment: I think it gives that warning when there's error produced by the compiled code (not an error in compiling it).  See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-compile-effectively/1814#1814) and others for more discussion.

Comment: `On[Compile::noinfo]` will cause a warning to be printed when you compile `A003986c`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ok, that makes sense, thanks. But what is so difficult about `snake` that can't be compiled? I can't seem to coax it into compiling.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12740/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-vf1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Whenever I click on the chat link, I get logged out - it seems to be some error.

Comment: @VF1 I display the "Proceding with ME..." warning only when a runtime condition causes evaluation to switch from the bytecode interpreter to the main evaluator.  It does not display this during compilation.  It only display this when you are running the function and when the switch is caused by a runtime (not compile time) condition.

Comment: I think you want `Compile[ ... , Evaluate@A003986[n], ...]`, otherwise the function won't be inlined.

Comment: In addition to Szabolcs' comment, you'll need to change `diag (diag - 1)/2` to `Quotient[diag (diag - 1), 2]`.

Comment: @RiemannZeta Why? It's guaranteed to be an even number.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the advice - I resorted to manually in-lining the functions. In this case, however, it's not so easy. I'll post an answer with what I ended up with.

Comment: @VF1, I was getting errors unless I did. It's because Compile turns `x/2` into `0.5*x`, giving you a `Real` instead of an `Integer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made two changes in your code and got a dramatic time drop: I changed `A003986[n]` to `Evaluate@A003986[n]` as Szabolcs suggested and I changed `diag (diag - 1)/2` to `Quotient[diag (diag - 1), 2]`.

```
Table[{x, A003986 /@ Range@(10^x); // Timing // First, 
     A003986c[Range@(10^x)]; // Timing // First}, {x, 5}]~
  Prepend~{"Func", "ME", "Comp"} // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: This explains m my error for my Ac2 function. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this so much faster than my `Ac3` and `Ac4`? Is the re-computation that results from direct inlining like you have done cheaper than writing to and storing repeated intermediate results?

Comment: Put `Block[{diag, temp}, ` within `Compile`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments by users @Szabolcs and @MichaelE2, the issue is that the function `A003986` is not inlined by `Compile` automatically so the compiled function just invokes `MainEvaluate`.

As recommended by @Szabolcs, inlining can be achieved by using `Evaluate`, as shown in the function `Ac2` (note I add the `Listable` attribute for speed):

```
Ac2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Evaluate@A003986[n], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Unfortunately, running `Ac2[3]` results in a run-time error because of some complications with `BitOr`.

Also, looking at the inlined function that results from the evaluation of the above one can see a couple repeated calculations. These in turn can be factored out as well, resulting in code which proceeds fully compiled:

```
Block[{diag, temp},
 Ac3 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
     diag = Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])];
     temp = n - diag (diag - 1)/2;
     BitOr[-1 + temp, 
      diag - temp], {{diag, _Integer}, {temp, _Integer}}, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];]
Table[{x, A003986 /@ Range[10^x]; // Timing // First, 
     Ac3[Range@(10^x)]; // Timing // First}, {x, 5}]~
  Prepend~{"Func", "ME", "Ac3"} // TableForm
```

[image]
And this version is even faster, though I don't know why:

```
Block[{res}, 
 Ac4 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
     Module[{diag = Ceiling[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 n])]}, 
      res = {-1, diag} + (n - diag (diag - 1)/2) {1, -1};
      BitOr[res // First, res // Last]], {{res, _Integer, 1}}, 
     CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];]
Table[{x, Ac3[Range[10^x]]; // Timing // First, 
     Ac4[Range[10^x]]; // Timing // First}, {x, 5}]~
  Prepend~{"Func", "Ac3", "Ac4"} // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you please explain the behavior at the bottom of my answer? Or do you think this merits another question?